# JavaScript: when I pass array from iframe function the array lose his type!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe in a form.
The iframe contains some info that I want deliver to the form parent by instance of Array.
The problem: the Array instance loses it's type and becomes an object!
The iframe function:

```
function getIDS2() { return new Array(); }
```

The parent call code:

```
alert(top.frames["sup_search"].getIDS2() instanceof Array);
```

Of course the answer for the alert is false...
So, I can fix it by doing this:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i =0; i < SuppliersIDs.length; i+=1) {
    arr.push(SuppliersIDs[i]);
}
```

Where SuppliersIDs is the delivered array and arr is the new true type array.
But why is this not working as I want it to?
By the way, is there any there a way to access the iframe func with jQuery??

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8):

Because each page has a global context with its own "Array" function, if code on one page passes an array to a function on a separate page, the test "array instanceof Array" will fail. For Array you can do this instead:

```
var arr = top.frames["sup_search"].getIDS2();
var isArray = arr && Object.prototype.toString.call(arr)=="[object Array]";
```

It feels hacky but it works.

Comment: It might feel hacky, but ECMA-262 defines the behaviour of `Object.prototype.toString()`, so it's guaranteed to work in conforming implementations

Answer (score 0):

@darin thanks for the answer.
You definitely found the problem
Actualy I want do some casting. I need to get it as an Array like the source.
I wrote the code like this:

```
var arr = new Array(SuppliersIDs);
```

The result is an array of objects not an array of integers as the original.

Answer (score 0):

I found way to access iframe function with jquery

```
$(this).contents()[0].defaultView.yourFunc()
```