# How can I check if an object is an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to write a function that either accepts a list of strings, or a single string. If it's a string, then I want to convert it to an array with just the one item so I can loop over it without fear of an error.

So how do I check if the variable is an array?

Comment: I thought you meant to 'check if object is an array', but you want to check if 'object is an array of strings or a single string' specifically.  Not sure if you see it?  Or is it just me? I was thinking of something more like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript?lq=1)... am I the one missing something here?

Comment: **TL;DR** - `arr.constructor === Array` is fastest.

Comment: You had an **important** part of the screenshot cut, above the test, where it's written where did the test occur. [My test](http://i.imgur.com/xxD71n8.png) is very different.

Comment: @vsync There's a hyperlink. You guys can run it as much as you like. The screenshot is there just for people that are too lazy to click.

Comment: http://jsben.ch/#/QgYAV - a benchmark for the most common ways

Comment: @Neta and what about `arr instanceof Array`?

Comment: @EscapeNetscape Your `prototype` test doesn't actually test anything.

Comment: **TL;DR** - Array.[isArray(arr)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) since ES5; and $.[isArray(arr)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/) in jQuery.

Comment: @sheelpriy > [].constructor === Array // 
true

Comment: how about just `typeof x === "string"` to see if it's a string, and if not you can assume it's an array for your use case

Comment: Just bear in mind that if you by any reason overwrite your constructor via prototype that `arr.constructor === Array` test will return false. `Array.isArray(arr)` still returns true though.

Comment: Watch out @Neta `arr.constructor` approach. Some considerations in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28467392/1358777)

Answer (score 1587, accepted):

In modern browsers you can do:

```
Array.isArray(obj)
```

([Supported by](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) Chrome 5, Firefox 4.0, Internet Explorer 9, [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) 10.5 and Safari 5)

For backward compatibility you can add the following:

```
// Only implement if no native implementation is available
if (typeof Array.isArray === 'undefined') {
  Array.isArray = function(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]';
  }
};
```

If you use jQuery you can use `jQuery.isArray(obj)` or `$.isArray(obj)`. If you use [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) you can use `_.isArray(obj)`.

If you don't need to detect arrays created in different frames you can also just use `instanceof`:

```
obj instanceof Array
```

Comment: Here is a [more complete](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.isArray) list of browsers that support `Array.isArray`

Comment: @NobleUplift: `instanceof Array` fails if the array is from a different frame because every array from that different frame has a different `Array` constructor and prototype. For compatibility/security reasons, every frame has its own global environment, and this includes global objects. The `Object` global from one frame is different from the `Object` global from another. So too for `Array` globals. [Axel Rauschmayer talks more about this](http://2ality.com/2013/01/categorizing-values.html).

Comment: Note that, as of 2022, this is very well supported (even back many browser versions): https://caniuse.com/?search=isArray

And also now the fastest method: http://jsben.ch/QgYAV

Answer (score 2062):

The method given in the ECMAScript standard to find the class of *Object* is to use the `toString` method from `Object.prototype`.

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(someVar) === '[object Array]') {
    alert('Array!');
}
```

Or you could use `typeof` to test if it is a *string*:

```
if(typeof someVar === 'string') {
    someVar = [someVar];
}
```

Or if you're not concerned about performance, you could just do a `concat` to a new empty Array.

```
someVar = [].concat(someVar);
```

There's also the constructor which you can query directly:

```
if (somevar.constructor.name == "Array") {
    // do something
}
```

---

Check out [a thorough treatment](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html) from [T.J. Crowder's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) blog, as posted in his comment below.

Check out [this benchmark](http://jsben.ch/#/QgYAV) to get an idea which method performs better: http://jsben.ch/#/QgYAV

From [@Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8432239/bharath?tab=profile), convert a string to an array using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) for the question asked:

```
const convertStringToArray = (object) => {
   return (typeof object === 'string') ? Array(object) : object
}
```

Suppose:

```
let m = 'bla'
let n = ['bla','Meow']
let y = convertStringToArray(m)
let z = convertStringToArray(n)
console.log('check y: '+JSON.stringify(y)) . // check y: ['bla']
console.log('check y: '+JSON.stringify(z)) . // check y: ['bla','Meow']
```

Comment: +1 Yup, `toString` is one of the ways to go. I do a bit of a roundup here: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html

Comment: If you don't want to type "[object Array]" use Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === Object.prototype.toString.call( [] ) or make a convenience function to get type if you don't want to type Object.prototype.toString.call

Comment: I use the vanilla Array.isArray which works in 'modern browsers' (that is, IE9+ and everyone else). And for old browser support use the shim from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: Live in the modern world - `Array.isArray(obj)`

Answer (score 1322):

I would first check if your implementation supports `isArray`:

```
if (Array.isArray)
    return Array.isArray(v);
```

You could also try using the `instanceof` operator

```
v instanceof Array
```

Comment: `v instanceof Array` will return false if `v` was created in another frame (`v` is instance of `thatFrame.contentWindow.Array` class).

Comment: To be specific: [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) is defined as part of ECMAScript 5/Javascript 1.8.5.

Answer (score 307):

jQuery also offers an [`$.isArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/) method:

```js
var a = ["A", "AA", "AAA"];

if($.isArray(a)) {
  alert("a is an array!");
} else {
  alert("a is not an array!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just a note, jQuery uses the toString method internally: [GitHub Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/cd4e25e991898bf07ce82fe4ab3d60c32b4a5fc9/test/libs/require.js#L45-L47)

Answer (score 111):

This is the fastest among all methods (all browsers supported):

```
function isArray(obj){
    return !!obj && obj.constructor === Array;
}
```

Answer (score 53):

Imagine you have this **array below**:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

JavaScript (new and older browsers):

```
function isArray(arr) {
  return arr.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") > -1;
}
```

or

```
function isArray(arr) {
  return arr instanceof Array;
}
```

or

```
function isArray(arr) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === '[object Array]';
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
isArray(arr);
```

JavaScript (Internet Explorer 9+, Chrome 5+, Firefox 4+, Safari 5+, and Opera 10.5+)

```
Array.isArray(arr);
```

jQuery:

```
$.isArray(arr);
```

Angular:

```
angular.isArray(arr);
```

Underscore.js and [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash):

```
_.isArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 35):

Array.isArray works fast, but it isn't supported by all versions of browsers.

So you could make an exception for others and use a universal method:

```
    Utils = {};
    Utils.isArray = ('isArray' in Array) ?
        Array.isArray :
        function (value) {
            return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]';
        }
```

Comment: Array.isArray is pretty much supported by all modern browsers now https://caniuse.com/?search=isArray

Answer (score 32):

A simple function to check this:

```
function isArray(object)
{
    return object.constructor === Array;
}
```

Comment: I'd reduce that down to one line `return object.constructor === Array` -- but are you sure that this will only return true for arrays?

Comment: Can do that with all boolean expressions. Drives me nuts when I see `if(x) return true; else return false` :-) Even if it's backwards, you should negate the expression.

Comment: This fails badly if object is undefined or null.

Answer (score 26):

You can use *[Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)*. Here is a polyfill:

```
if (Array.isArray == null) {
  Array.isArray = (arr) => Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === "[object Array]"
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? E.g., why is "Array.isArray" on both sides of the "="? "Array.isArray" is a method. What is the principle of operation? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15219005/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 21):

As MDN says [in here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Normal_cases):

> use **Array.isArray** or **Object.prototype.toString.call** to differentiate
>   regular objects from arrays

Like this:

- `Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === '[object Array]'`, or
- `Array.isArray(arr)`

Answer (score 21):

There's just one line solution for this question

```
x instanceof Array
```

where x is the variable it will return true if x is an array and false if it is not.

Answer (score 18):

I would make a function to test the type of object you are dealing with...

```js
function whatAmI(me){ return Object.prototype.toString.call(me).split(/\W/)[2]; }

// tests
console.log(
  whatAmI(["aiming","@"]),
  whatAmI({living:4,breathing:4}),
  whatAmI(function(ing){ return ing+" to the global window" }),
  whatAmI("going to do with you?")
);

// output: Array Object Function String
```

then you can write a simple if statement...

```
if(whatAmI(myVar) === "Array"){
    // do array stuff
} else { // could also check `if(whatAmI(myVar) === "String")` here to be sure
    // do string stuff
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can check the type of your variable whether it is an array with;

```
var myArray=[];

if(myArray instanceof Array)
{
....
}
```

Comment: A few people have already mentioned `instanceof`.. I think it fails under a few weird scenarios.

Answer (score 14):

I do this in a very simple way. It works for me.

```
Array.prototype.isArray = true;

a=[]; b={};
a.isArray  // true
b.isArray  // (undefined -> false)
```

Comment: fooled by `{isArray:true}`

Comment: `JSON.parse(someDataFromElsewhere).items.isArray` could return true (depending on the data) and break your code.

Answer (score 13):

This is my attempt to improve on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12268916/34806) taking into account the comments:

```
var isArray = myArray && myArray.constructor === Array;
```

It gets rid of the if/else, and accounts for the possibility of the array being null or undefined

Comment: constructor is not available in ES5

Answer (score 13):

The best practice is to compare it using `constructor`, something like this

```
if(some_variable.constructor === Array){
  // do something
}
```

You can use other methods too, like `typeOf`, converting it to a string and then comparing, but comparing it with dataType is always a better approach.

Answer (score 12):

I know, that people are looking for some kind of raw JavaScript approach. But if you want think less about it, take a look at [Underscore.js'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) *[isArray](http://underscorejs.org/#isArray)*:

```
_.isArray(object)
```

It returns true if *object* is an Array.

```
(function(){ return _.isArray(arguments); })();
=> false
_.isArray([1,2,3]);
=> true
```

Comment: "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score 12):

I have updated the [jsperf fiddle](http://jsperf.com/check-isarray/3) with two alternative methods as well as error checking.

It turns out that the method defining a constant value in the 'Object' and 'Array' prototypes is faster than any of the other methods.  It is a somewhat surprising result.

```js
/* Initialisation */
Object.prototype.isArray = function() {
  return false;
};
Array.prototype.isArray = function() {
  return true;
};
Object.prototype._isArray = false;
Array.prototype._isArray = true;

var arr = ["1", "2"];
var noarr = "1";

/* Method 1 (function) */
if (arr.isArray()) document.write("arr is an array according to function<br/>");
if (!noarr.isArray()) document.write("noarr is not an array according to function<br/>");
/* Method 2 (value) - **** FASTEST ***** */
if (arr._isArray) document.write("arr is an array according to member value<br/>");
if (!noarr._isArray) document.write("noarr is not an array according to member value<br/>");
```

These two methods do not work if the variable takes the undefined value, but they do work if you are certain that they have a value.  With regards to checking with performance in mind if a value is an array or a single value, the second method looks like a valid fast method.  It is slightly faster than 'instanceof' on Chrome, twice as fast as the second best method in Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari (on my machine).

Answer (score 6):

The best solution I've seen is a cross-browser replacement for typeof. Check [Angus Croll's solution](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/).

The TL;DR version is below, but the article is a great discussion of the issue so you should read it if you have time.

```
Object.toType = function(obj) {
    return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-z|A-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}
// ... and usage:
Object.toType([1,2,3]); //"array" (all browsers)

// or to test...
var shouldBeAnArray = [1,2,3];
if(Object.toType(shouldBeAnArray) === 'array'){/* do stuff */};
```

Answer (score 5):

If the only two kinds of values that could be passed to this function are a string or an array of strings, keep it simple and use a `typeof` check for the string possibility:

```
function someFunc(arg) {
    var arr = (typeof arg == "string") ? [arg] : arg;
}
```

Comment: Yeah... that'd work for this scenario, but not in general. Ended up using varargs anyway. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's my lazy approach:

```
if (Array.prototype.array_ === undefined) {
  Array.prototype.array_ = true;
}

// ...

var test = [],
    wat = {};

console.log(test.array_ === true); // true
console.log(wat.array_ === true);  // false
```

I know it's sacrilege to "mess with" the prototype, but [it appears to perform significantly better than the recommended `toString` method](http://jsperf.com/isarray-approaches).

**Note:** A pitfall of this approach is that it [wont work across `iframe` boundaries](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/), but for my use case this is not an issue.

Comment: its not better in terms of performance anymore, at least on FF30 on Ubuntu 64-bit

Comment: fooled by `wat = {array_: true}` objects.

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, that should be obvious. If you're setting `obj.array_ = true`, then you're *only fooling yourself*.

Comment: @namuol: I'm not necessarily fooling myself. Often enough objects are used as dictionaries. Think of a `cache` object to memoize search results which uses the search strings as property keys. What if a user searches for `array_`? Does your object become an array because of that? It's just a bug.

Comment: @namuol: Also, this approach would require that all involved parties (including used libraries) can agree that `.array_` is used for tagging arrays. That's really not the case here, `.array` can mean anything. You should at least use a descriptive string, and signal inappropriateness of arbitrary use, e.g. with `.__isArray = true`.

Comment: Agreed! Naming is important. This answer was just a quick hack meant to be used "in a vacuum" -- not really meant for use in libraries.

Comment: Potentially fooled by `JSON.parse(someDataFromElsewhere).items.array_` returning true.

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice example in Stoyan Stefanov's book [JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) which is supposed to handle all possible problems as well as use the ECMAScript 5 method [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

So here it is:

```
if (typeof Array.isArray === "undefined") {
    Array.isArray = function (arg) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === "[object Array]";
    };
}
```

By the way, if you are using jQuery, you can use its method [$.isArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/).

Comment: +1: why not just a simple `if(!Array.isArray) {...` ?

Answer (score 5):

The following could be used if you know that your object doesn't have a concat method.

```js
var arr = [];
if (typeof arr.concat === 'function') {
    console.log("It's an array");
}
```

Comment: This is a good trick, but could be overridden... but most of the times should get the result

Answer (score 5):

This function will turn almost anything into an array:

```
function arr(x) {
    if(x === null || x === undefined) {
        return [];
    }
    if(Array.isArray(x)) {
        return x;
    }
    if(isString(x) || isNumber(x)) {
        return [x];
    }
    if(x[Symbol.iterator] !== undefined || x.length !== undefined) {
        return Array.from(x);
    }
    return [x];
}

function isString(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object String]"
}

function isNumber(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Number]"
}
```

It uses some newer browser features so you may want to polyfill this for maximum support.

Examples:

```
> arr(null);
[]
> arr(undefined)
[]
> arr(3.14)
[ 3.14 ]
> arr(1/0)
[ Infinity ]
> gen = function*() { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; }
[Function: gen]
> arr(gen())
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> arr([4,5,6])
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
> arr("foo")
[ 'foo' ]
```

N.B. strings will be converted into an array with a single element instead of an array of chars. Delete the `isString` check if you would prefer it the other way around.

I've used `Array.isArray` here because it's the [most robust](http://web.mit.edu/jwalden/www/isArray.html) and also simplest.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and fastest way to check if an Object is an Array or not.

```
var arr = [];
arr.constructor.name === 'Array'  // Returns true;
```

or

```
arr.constructor === Array // Returns true;
```

Or you can make a utility function:

```
const isArray = (obj) => !!obj && obj.constructor === Array;
```

Usage:

```
isArray(arr); // Returns true
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the *isArray* method, but I would prefer to check with:

`Object.getPrototypeOf(yourvariable) === Array.prototype`

Comment: Why would you prefer this?

Comment: @mpen `Object.getPrototypeOf(yourvariable)` it returns prototype of an Array object. And The code is fastest and safe to rely on.

Comment: It's easy to foil: https://pastebin.com/MP8d5bCE Also, do you have performance tests to back up your "fastest" claim?

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = [], b = {};

console.log(a.constructor.name == "Array");
console.log(b.constructor.name == "Object");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Code only answers tend to be overlooked, would you mind adding some explanation to your code?

Answer (score 4):

```
A = [1,2,3]
console.log(A.map == [].map)
```

In search for the shortest version, here is what I got so far.

Note, there is no perfect function that will always detect all possible combinations. **It is better to know all abilities and limitations of your tools than expect a magic tool.**

Comment: slight derivation of mine `A.map !== undefined` but yeah, that could be slippy road in the world of monkey patchers ;)

Comment: FYI: This doesn't work across iFrames (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460256/javascript-when-i-pass-array-from-iframe-function-the-array-lose-his-type/460427#460427)

Comment: Why does it work? What is the principle of operation? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15352516/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

```
function isArray(value) {
    if (value) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            return (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) == '[object Array]')
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var ar = ["ff","tt"]
alert(isArray(ar))
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19669468/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

A simple function for testing if an input value is an array is the following:

```
function isArray(value)
{
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]';
}
```

This works cross browser, and with older browsers. This is [pulled from T.J. Crowders' blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
var arr = []; (or) arr = new Array();
var obj = {}; (or) arr = new Object();

arr.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty('push') //true

obj.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty('push') // false
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case you may use `concat` method of [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which can accept single objects as well as array (and even combined):

```
function myFunc(stringOrArray)
{
  var arr = [].concat(stringOrArray);

  console.log(arr);

  arr.forEach(function(item, i)
  {
    console.log(i, "=", item);
  })
}

myFunc("one string");

myFunc(["one string", "second", "third"]);
```

`concat` seems to be one of the oldest methods of Array (even IE 5.5 knows it well).

Answer (score 4):

Although there's some solid answers I would prefer a functional approach using a *[functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_(functional_programming))*. A functor is just a fancy way to say that we will be passing a function to a value. (The suggestions that I've seen are passing values to a function.)

**Create a TypeOf helper**

```
const TypeOf = obj => Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8,-1);
```

This is similar to typeof, but it now returns `Array` for `[]` and `Object` for `{}`. I like to think of it as a strict *typeof*. If you're working on the Gmail application and performance is a concern then you can do something like this.

```
const TypeOf = obj => (
  Array.isArray(obj)
   ? "array"
    : obj === null // catch null edge case.  typeof null is an object :)
   ? null
    : typeof obj
)
```

You could stop here and call it a day. However, you could make it a bit more powerful using composition.  You get a lot of benefits if you created a TypeBox Functor, again fancy word for passing a function to a value instead of passing a value to a function.

**Create TypeBox**

```
const TypeBox = (predicate, defaultValue) => {
  const TypePredicate = value => ({
     value,
     map: cb => predicate(value)
                ? TypePredicate(cb(value))
                : TypePredicate(defaultValue)
  });
  return TypePredicate;
}
```

There's a lot going on here, but it's very powerful.  The TypeBox function uses a closure and returns our Functor.  Closures give you access to Lexical_Scope. Think of it as a backpack that holds the things you want access to later.

**Create ArrayBox**

```
const ArrayBox = TypeOf(obj => TypeOf(obj) === 'Array' ? obj : [obj]);
```

ArrayBox is passing our `predicate` and `defaultValue` to `TypeOf` and will be available when we invoke/execute `ArrayBox`(name it whatever makes sense for your use case).

**Now the fun part**

If the input is an Array, return it.

```
ArrayBox(["foo", "bar"]).value; // ['foo', 'bar']
```

If the input is not an array, return it in one

```
ArrayBox("foo").value // ["foo"]
```

What's great about this approach is that it scales, is easy to test, and it uses composition.  You can compose the functions in any manner to get the desired result.

There's many other ways we could approach this using Either or [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)).

Answer (score 4):

### Exotic one

You want to check if the parameter is a string or not - so try

```
x===x+''
```

```js
let isStr = x=> x===x+'';

console.log( isStr([]) );
console.log( isStr(["aa","bb"]) );
console.log( isStr("") );
console.log( isStr("abc") );
```

Comment: Cool, so if not isStr does not mean is Array...  nice play with a syntax however.

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully, ECMAScript 5 introduced `Array.isArray()` back in December 2009. If for some reason, you are using a version of JavaScript older than ECMAScript 5, please upgrade.

If you insist on it, though, then arrays do have certain properties that differentiate them from any other type. Properties that I haven't seen mentioned in any of the other answers. Let's get into some JavaScript politics.

An array is an object (`typeof [] === "object"`), but unlike traditional objects, they have a length property (`typeof ( {} ).length === "undefined"`). `null` is *also* an object (`typeof null === "object"`), but you can't access a property of `null` because `null` is *not* an object.

This is a bug in the specification that goes all the way back to the very beginning of JavaScript, when objects had the type tag `0` and `null` was represented as a literal null pointer `0x00`, which caused the interpreter to confuse it with objects.

Unfortunately, this doesn't account for `[]` vs. `{length:0}`. So we must now turn to the prototype chain.

`( [] ).__proto__ === Array.prototype && ( [] ).__proto__ !== Object.prototype`.

Thus, without `Array.isArray()`, this is just about the closest we can get:

```
function is_array(array){
    return array !== null
        && typeof array === "object"
        && array.__proto__ === Array.prototype;
}

[ [], [1,2,3], {length: 0}, {},
  1, 0, Infinity, NaN, "1", "[1,2,3]",
  null, undefined, [null], [undefined], {a:[]},
  [{}], [{length: 0}], [Infinity], [NaN],
  {__proto__: Array.prototype}
].filter(is_array)
// Expected: [ [], [1,2,3], [null], [undefined], [{}], [{length: 0}], [Infinity], [NaN] ]
// Actual:   [ [], [1,2,3], [null], [undefined], [{}], [{length: 0}], [Infinity], [NaN], {__proto__: Array.prototype} ]
```

The object maliciously designed to look just like an array actually passes the [Turing test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test). However, replacing the prototype chain with the Array prototype chain is enough to make it act just like an array, effectively making it an array.

The only thing in the world that can tell such an object is actually not an array, is `Array.isArray()`. But for the purposes you would usually be checking if an object is an array, said object should play nice with your code.

Even the behavior when you change the length of the array artificially is the same: if the length is longer than the number of elements in the array, you *will* have "empty slots" of that special "implicit undefined" type that is somehow distinct from undefined while also being `=== undefined`; the very same type that is the reason we use `typeof obj !== "undefined"` to avoid throwing a `ReferenceError` because `obj === undefined` only *doesn't* throw an error if `obj` was explicitly defined as `undefined`.

```
a = {__proto__: Array.prototype}; // Array {}
a.push(5)
a // [5]
a.length = 5
a // [5, empty x 4]
b = a.map(n => n*n) // [25, empty x 4]
b.push(undefined)
b.push(undefined)
b // [25, empty x 4, undefined, undefined]
b[1] // undefined
b[1] === b[5] // true
Array.isArray(a) // false
Array.isArray(b) // true
```

Don't use `is_array()`, though. It's one thing to reinvent the wheel for learning purposes. It's another thing to do it in production code. Don't even use it as a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)). Supporting old JavaScript versions means supporting old browsers means encouraging the use of insecure software means putting the user at risk for malware.

Comment: I'd be okay with removing `is_array` from the answer entirely and just replacing it with a brief explanation that checking an object's `__proto__` against `Array.prototype` may distinguish arrays from most "array-disguised objects", but is no substitute for `Array.isArray` because polyfills and NIH syndrome can be dangerous. I'll get to it later if I have time.

Answer (score 2):

Other methods also exist to check, but I prefer the following method as my best way to check (as you can easily check types of other objects).

```
> a = [1, 2]
[ 1, 2 ]
>
> Object.prototype.toString.call(a).slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'Array'
>
> Object.prototype.toString.call([]).slice(8,-1) // best approach
'Array'
```

Explanation (with simple examples on Node REPL)»

```
> o = {'ok': 1}
{ ok: 1 }
> a = [1, 2]
[ 1, 2 ]
> typeof o
'object'
> typeof a
'object'
>
> Object.prototype.toString.call(o)
'[object Object]'
> Object.prototype.toString.call(a)
'[object Array]'
>
```

Object or Array »

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'Object'
>
> Object.prototype.toString.call(a).slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'Array'
>
```

Null or Undefined »

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined).slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'Undefined'
> Object.prototype.toString.call(null).slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'Null'
>
```

String »

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call('ok').slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'String'
```

Number »

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call(19).slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'Number'
> Object.prototype.toString.call(19.0).slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'Number'
> Object.prototype.toString.call(19.7).slice(8,).replace(/\]$/, '')
'Number'
>
```

I appreciate `@mpen`'s suggestion to use -1 in place of regular expression as follows.

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call(12).slice(8,-1)
'Number'
>
> Object.prototype.toString.call(12.0).slice(8,-1)
'Number'
>
> Object.prototype.toString.call([]).slice(8,-1)
'Array'
> Object.prototype.toString.call({}).slice(8,-1)
'Object'
>
> Object.prototype.toString.call('').slice(8,-1)
'String'
>
```

Comment: You might as well use `-1` as the 2nd arg to `slice` and save the regex for a rainy day.

Comment: Thanks `@mpen`. I have added your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I found the shortest answer now:

```js
var x = [1,2,3]
console.log(x.map?1:0)
```

Comment: why `? 1 : 0` if you're going for the shortest answer, why not `!!x.map` or even just `x.map`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I came up with and have been using for my projects...

```
function isArray (o) {
    return typeof o === "object" && o.length !== undefined;
}

isArray({}); // false
isArray(1); // false
isArray("str"); // false
isArray(function(){}); // false

isArray([]); // true
```

The only pitfall is that it will give a false positive if your object happens to have a length property:

```
isArray({length:0}); // true
```

If you are okay with that drawback and know your pure objects won't have that property, it's a clean solution and should be faster than the Object.prototype.toString.call method.

Comment: isArray( new String() ); returns true

Comment: Yes, I noted that as a pitfall in my comments below the examples:

"The only pitfall is that it will give a false positive if your object happens to have a length property"

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var is_array = function (value) {
   return value &&
     typeof value === 'object' &&
     typeof value.length === 'number' &&
     typeof value.splice === 'function' &&
    !(value.propertyIsEnumerable('length'));
};
```

This function has been taken from "[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford#Bibliography)" book, and it works perfect for me.

Comment: `var object = {splice: function(){}}; Object.defineProperty(object, "length", {value: 1, enumerable: false}); console.log(is_array(object));`

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't like any Object.prototype-calls, I searched for another solution. Especially because [the solutions of ChaosPandion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/how-can-i-check-if-an-object-is-an-array/4775741#4775741) won't always work, and the [solution of MidnightTortoise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/how-can-i-check-if-an-object-is-an-array/12268916#12268916) with `isArray()` doesn't work with arrays coming from the DOM (like *getElementsByTagName*). And finally I found an easy and cross-browser solution, which probably also would have worked with Netscape 4. ;)

It's just these four lines (checking any object `h`):

```
function isArray(h){
    if((h.length!=undefined&&h[0]!=undefined)||(h.length===0&&h[0]===undefined)){
        return true;
    }
    else{ return false; }
}
```

I already tested these arrays (all return true):

```
1) array=d.getElementsByName('some_element'); //'some_element' can be a real or unreal element
2) array=[];
3) array=[10];
4) array=new Array();
5) array=new Array();
   array.push("whatever");
```

Does this work for all cases? Or is there a case where my solution doesn't work?

Comment: Too many false positives. `isArray(function(){}); // true`, `isArray("foo"); // true`, `isArray({length:0}); // true`

Comment: ...and a NodeList isn't an Array anyway.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your test results. This is getting my a lot more insight how Javascript works internally.

Comment: The usage of charAt just vanished everywhere out of my code. ;)

Comment: It turned out that in JS all strings are functions: `alert("foo".constructor);`, and arrays are functions: `var bar=["id","12345"]; alert(bar.constructor);`, or even structures like this: `foobar={"id":"12345"};` which can be proved by `alert(foobar.constructor);`. But the problem is: Some functions are even arrays, e.g. strings are array. ;)

Comment: The prove: `"foo"[0] //returns "f"!`, so strings are arrays and `"foo".charAt(0)` is not really needed in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the data type.

```
var myAr = [1,2];

checkType(myAr);

function checkType(data) {
  if(typeof data ==='object') {
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(data).indexOf('Array') !== (-1)) {
      return 'array';
    } else {
      return 'object';
    }
  } else {
    return typeof data;
  }
}

if(checkType(myAr) === 'array') {
  console.log('yes, it is an array')
};
```

Comment: All the op asked for was a simple efficient check.

Answer (score 0):

You can find with `push` like below:

```js
function isArray(obj){
   return (typeof obj.push === 'function') ? true : false;
}

var array = new Array();

or

var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(isArray(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between checking out its prototype and Array.isArray:

```
function isArray(obj){
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Array.prototype
}
```

This function will directly check if an obj is an array.

But for this Proxy object:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]

var proxy = new Proxy(arr,{})

console.log(Array.isArray(proxy)) // true
```

`Array.isArray` will take it as Array.

Comment: You seem to be implying that your `isArray` function *won't* return true for the Proxy, but that's not the case; they both return `true` for the Proxy (and unproxied arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet that'll explain an important fact of arrays that should be known early on while learning JavaScript (unlike me).

```js
// this functions puts a string inside an array
var stringInsideArray = function(input) {
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    return [input];
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return input;
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("Input is not a string!");
  }
}

var output = stringInsideArray('hello');
console.log('step one output: ', output); // ["hello"]

// use typeof method to verify output is an object
console.log('step two output: ', typeof output); // object

// use Array.isArray() method to verify output is an array
console.log('step three output: ', Array.isArray(output)); // true
```

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), are in fact, objects.

Using the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator, the output of `stringInsideArray('hello')` proves that `["hello"]` is **really** an object. This baffled me for the longest time because I assumed that arrays would be a JavaScript data type...

There are only seven JavaScript data types and [arrays are **not**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) one of them.

To answer your question, using the [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method determines that the `output` is an array.

Comment: Just FYI, `[].concat(string)` is kind of a weird way of writing `[string]`.

Comment: @mpen thanks for letting me know. out of curiosity, how would you write this?

Comment: `function toArray(x) { if(x === undefined) return []; if(Array.isArray(x)) return x; return [x]; }` or possibly `[...x]` for the middle case depending on whether or not you expect a new array to be returned.

Comment: @mpen your solution makes a lot more sense. updating my answer accordingly. thanks!

Comment: You're quietly suppressing numbers and other non-string inputs if you write it that way. If you only want to allow strings then you should throw an Error if they don't provide one. The scenario I had in mind would allow arrays of anything.

Comment: when you say Error, something like this for the else statement?
`else {
    throw "Input is not a string!";
 }`

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't throw bare strings. Try `throw new Error("Input is not a string!")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.isArray` is the way to go about this. For example:

```
var arr = ['tuna', 'chicken', 'pb&j'];
var obj = {sandwich: 'tuna', chips: 'cape cod'};

// Returns true
Array.isArray(arr);

// Return false
Array.isArray(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can check *console.log(typeof Object)*.

If the output is object then
var {data}=object, i.e., just destructure the object according to the object keys.

And the function can be like this:

```
const abc = (str1, str2=null) => {
    var result = [];
    result.push(str1);
    result.push(str2);
    return result.join("");
}
```

Comment: FYI, `typeof []` is "object", `typeof ""` is "string", and `typeof new String('')` is "object". This is not a great way to differentiate.

Comment: Yeah you are right.i meant to say that console.log(typeof variableName) to get the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

// In simple ways

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const obj = { message: 'nice' };
const str = 'nice';
const empty = null;

console.log(Array.isArray(arr));
console.log(Array.isArray(obj));
console.log(Array.isArray(str));
console.log(Array.isArray(empty));
```

Comment: Isn't *Array.isArray* covered by previous answers?

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I use:

```
function isArray(input) {
  if (input instanceof Array || Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Array]') {
        return true;
  } else return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also check with array's *length* property. When you will try to access the *length* property of an array, it will return a number (0 for an empty array) while if you try to access the *length* property of object it will return undefined.

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(arrayList) === '[object Array]') {
  console.log('Array!');
}
```

Comment: Your paragraph and code example don't align. Also, objects can have a `.length` property.

Comment: You can't check object length. Can u give me a example of object's length property

Comment: `{length:5}` boom. an object with a length property.

Answer (score -1):

Array.isArray(obj) does not give very helpful results. I've created a prototype method of Object that seems to correctly determine whether and object is an array or not.

The only edge case that I know of where it fails is when item in the array is set to undefined.

```
Object.prototype.isArrayLike = function()
{
    var length = this.length || Object.keys(this).length;
    if (length === 0 || this.constructor.name === "String")
        return false;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (typeof this[i] === "undefined")
            return false;
    }
    return true;
};

var arr = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'];
var arr1 = {"0":'aaa', "1":'bbb', 2:'ccc', 3:'ddd'};
var arr2 = {"0":'aaa', "a":'bbb', 2:'ccc', 3:'ddd'};
var arr3 = "qwerty";
var arr4 = [];
var arr5 = {0:'aaa', 1:'bbb', 2:'ccc', 3:'ddd'};

console.log("arrayLike:" + arr.isArrayLike());
console.log("Array.isArray(arr):" + Array.isArray(arr));
// arrayLike: true
// Array.isArray(arr): true
console.log("arrayLike1:" + arr1.isArrayLike());
console.log("Array.isArray(arr1):" + Array.isArray(arr1));
// arrayLike1: true
// Array.isArray(arr1): false
console.log("arrayLike2:" + arr2.isArrayLike());
console.log("Array.isArray(arr2):" + Array.isArray(arr2));
// arrayLike2: false
// Array.isArray(arr2): false
console.log("arrayLike3:" + arr3.isArrayLike());
console.log("Array.isArray(arr3):" + Array.isArray(arr3));
// arrayLike3: false
// Array.isArray(arr3): false
console.log("arrayLike4:" + arr4.isArrayLike());
console.log("Array.isArray(arr4):" + Array.isArray(arr4));
// arrayLike4: false
// Array.isArray(arr4): true
console.log("arrayLike5:" + arr5.isArrayLike());
console.log("Array.isArray(arr5):" + Array.isArray(arr5));
// arrayLike5: false
// Array.isArray(arr5): true
```

Answer (score -4):

```
 var length = 16;                               // Number
 var lastName = "Johnson";                      // String
 var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];           // Array
 var x = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"};

 Object.prototype.myCheck= function(){
 if (this.constructor === Array){
          alert('array');
        }else if (this.constructor === Object)
       {
         alert('object');
        }else if (this.constructor === Number)
        {
          alert('number');
        }else if (this.constructor === String)
        {
          alert('string');
        }

 }
 cars.myCheck();
 lastName.myCheck();
 length.myCheck();
```

Comment: Why did you make your method a prototype of Object if you aren't going to call it like `cars.myCheck()`?

Comment: yes mark you are correct it should be cars.myCheck().. updated the answer

Comment: Still no. If you're making it a prototype method, you should drop the `obj` argument and use `this` inside instead. Also, a function that just alerts isn't of much use to anyone.