# json - what to do when json data returns as [ ] aka empty/null

Tags: jquery, json

Quick question:

I'm using jquery ajax to call a page that returns some json data. Sometimes it returns full of data and sometimes it returns empty as `[]`.

I want the script to do different things if it comes back empty`[]` or with data. Everything is working fine when it returns with data, but I can't seem to get things to work when it returns empty as `[]`. Here's what i have:

```
success: function (returndata){
      if (returndata === null)
      {
          $("#versionBox").remove();
      }
 else {
        $.each(returndata, function()
               {
                   var tag = this["name"];
                   var linkname = "textdisplay.php?flag=<?php echo $fs; ?>&ed=" + tag;
                       $('#versionBox').append("<p><a href='" + linkname + "'>" +  tag + "</a></p>");
               });

      }
```

But `null` doesn't seem to be the correct way to describe `[]` because the first part of this script isn't working.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if it's an array [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array), then if its returndata.length == 0. Done & done!

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( returnData ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    if(returnData.length == 0)
        alert( 'it is []' );
}
```

The "is it an array" check isn't very satisfying, I know...

Answer (score 3):

What you perceive as "empty" is an array with no elements. Arrays have a `length` property, so:

```
if (returndata.length == 0) // "empty" return
```

This assumes that `returndata` is an array in every case (otherwise, it might have no `length` and you will get errors), but in your case it looks it is indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (returndata){
    //if the return data has content
} else {
    //when it does not
}
```