# How to judge a javascript variable's datatype is Array?

Tags: javascript, object, types

I have try three way in the bellow, the result is comment on the right,the diffcult is I can't different it from `Object` datatype.How can I get it datatype like `Array` or `String` but not `Object`?

```
   var arr = [];
   console.log('type of arr', typeof arr); //objct
   console.log('instanceof array', arr instanceof Array); //true
   console.log('instanceof object', arr instanceof Object);  // true
```

Comment: By the way, [this has already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array always will be instance of object - `Object` is the base object in javascript and any another  object created by new is inherited from.

```
 new String('a') instanceof Object // true - also instance of String
 new Number(3) instanceof Object // true -also instance of Number etc.
 new Boolean(true) instanceof Object // true
 new Date instanceof Object // true
 new function(){} instanceof Object // true

 [] instanceof Object // true - [] is equal to new Array

 check this out: 
 Array = 1;
 [] //TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
 :)
```

however

```
'a' instanceof Object // false
 3 instanceof Object // false
```

Try this:

```
 var str = 'aaa',
     arr  = [],
     myClass = function(){},
     myClassInstance = new myClass;

 str.constructor == String // true
 arr.constructor == Array // true
 myClassInstance.constructor == myClass // true
```

Comment: (new Date(3) instanceof Object) returns true. While you may be able to create new Date(3) and get a valid date, 3 is not a date, it's a number. Within the confines of array detection, this method may work, but the expanded answer described is misleading for other usages.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one technique:

```
> var arr = [];
> Object.prototype.toString.call(arr);
"[object Array]"
```

What this does is call the `toString` method of the prototype object, using whatever is passed in as the `this` pointer. For more information on this technique, see [the reference on `call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

It turns out that you can use this technique to figure out other object types as well:

```
> var func = function(){}
> Object.prototype.toString.call(func);
"[object Function]"

> var obj = {};
> Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
"[object Object]"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use jQuery's "isArray" function for this

```
var arr1 =[];
alert(jQuery.isArray(arr1));  // true

var arr2 = new Array();
alert(jQuery.isArray(arr2));  // true

var obj = new Object();
alert(jQuery.isArray(obj));   // false
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this info at MDN - In Javascript Version 1.8.5 Array.isArray is added and it is standard in ECMAScript 5

```
// all following calls return true
Array.isArray([]);
Array.isArray([1]);
Array.isArray( new Array() );
Array.isArray( Array.prototype ); // Little known fact: Array.prototype itself is an array.
```

Also if isArray is not available

```
if(!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function (vArg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(vArg) === "[object Array]";
  };
}
```

For more details at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, your question is your answer indeed,

```
var arr = [];
if('instanceof object', arr instanceof Object){
    alert('arr is a object');
    if('instanceof array', arr instanceof Array){
        alert('arr is a Array');
    }
}​else{
    alert('this is not a object');
}
```

Now let's use a simple variable testObj, This is not even a object then how it could be a array,

```
    var testObj;
    if('instanceof object', testObj instanceof Object){
      alert('testObj is a object');
    }else{
      alert('testObj is not a object');
    }
​
```

Try this for [more](http://jsfiddle.net/37Rc6/)