# Javascript Array constructor property not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

Any object Constructor property return its constructor function, but it doesnt work for Array.

```
var o={};
o.constructor; --> returns Object()

var a=new Array();
a.constructor; --> Expecting Array() but it returns [undefined]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Actually in Chrome and IE both versions return a function. What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to detect whether its an array or not though we have other workaround (a.length>0)..

Comment: Uh, `your_object instanceof Array`? Better, isn't it?

Comment: To check if an object is an array you can use `Object.prototype.toString.call(your_object) == '[object Array]'`

Comment: More detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array

Comment: Be careful with constructor : it will throws a TypeError if your object is null. As explain in this good article on types checking : http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

The `constructor` property of an object will refer to a function. Instead to check if a variable holds an array, do this:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(a)==='[object Array]') alert('Array!');
```

The proposed a.length workaround will not work 100 % because it's possible to have an object that has the length property without being an actual array.

Comment: cool. yeah you are correct. ".length" property works with the other object. thanks for ur time.