# Initializing Array members in Typescript

Tags: typescript

How do I initialize an array member in the following class.

```
   class EventObject {
        map:Array;
        constructor() {
            this.map = [];  // error :Cannot convert 'any[]' to  'Array'
            this.map = new Array(); // error :Cannot convert 'any[]' to  'Array'
        };
}

var obj = new EventObject();
console.log(obj.map[0]);
```

Also, I am able to initialize it if I change the type to number[] . But then, I get an error when I check if it is an instanceof Array :

```
class EventObject {
            map:number[];
            constructor() {
                this.map = [];
                if(this.map instanceof Array)  //error here
                    alert("Type checking");
            };
}
```

I want to do both : initialize and  check instanceof (or typeof)

**How is the Javascript Array different from  an array in Typescript ( represented by '[]' )** ?

Comment: To answer *How is the Javascript Array different from an array in Typescript ( represented by '[]' ) ?*, they should be equivalent : http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/812

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map: number[];
```

Is the correct syntax.

There's several reasons not to use instacenof Array. See here: [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array)

If you want to use instanceof, you must cast the left operator like:

```
var m: number[];
if (<any>m instanceof Array) {
}
```