# Backbone fetch parent model with nested collection

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, model, nested, fetch

My aplication has this structure:

```
Project (model)
     -> tracks (collection)
           -> track (model)
                 -> clips (collection)
                         clip (model)
```

I need to fetch only parent project model. It will cause change of all data structure. I get JSON

```
{ "_id" : "123",
  "name" : "name",
  "tracks" : [ { "clips" : [ { "audioName" : "audio name",
              "audioPath" : "audio/path.wav",
              "duration" : 123,
              "id" : "track0-1"
            } ],
        "mute" : false,
        "name" : "track0",
        "selected" : false,
        "volume" : 100
      },
      { "clips" : [  ],
        "mute" : false,
        "name" : "track1",
        "selected" : false,
        "volume" : 100
      }
   ]
}
```

I have parse method:

```
    parse: function (data) { 
        this.get('tracks').reset(data.tracks);
        delete data.tracks;
        return data;
    }
```

I am not able to parse clips. In model track, attribute clips has behavior like javascript array instead of backbone model.

How can I parse clips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parse` is only used to parse responses from the server. So you won't be able to use it to create your `clips` collection.
So you may want to change the way you do that (maybe have a look at Backbone-relational, I think it deals with this kind of stuff). Here's a possible solution (to be put in your model):

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this, 'change:clips', this.onChangeClips);
  // the rest of your stuff
},
onChangeClips: function() {
  var clips = this.get('clips');
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(clips) === '[object Array]')
    this.set('clips', new Clips(clips), {silent: true});
}
```

Source to test if array: [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array)

Note: this will remove any reference to an existing collection (which you seem to have), so you may want to keep a reference to your collection in your model (like in a `_clips` attribute) to reset it with the new `clips` array.

Comment: thank you, very much. This command:  "this.set('clips', new Clips(clips), {silent: true});" is, what I search for. Thank you. Now it works.