# html table based upon json object tree

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've got a dynamic json object that can contain different types of attributes and objects inside, could have plane strings or even arrays.
I made a javascript code to convert a single JSON structure to an HTML table, worked great but id like to make it for a dynamic JSON, so basically I would need to iterate through the JSON tree parents and childs to see how do i create this HTML table.

But I do have some problems when trying to validate if a child has an object inside, like this: ( I don't want to add to many details to the JSON)

```
parent: {
    child_1: {
        attr1 : value1
    },
    child_2: {
          [{ attribues and values in an array }]
    }
}
```

How could I achieve this? I was thinking of using the "typeof" function like so:

```
if (typeof key === 'array') {
    // do something
}else{
    // do another stuff
}
```

But I don't believe it would work well, can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it should work OK. Use a recursive function to build up the table.

Comment: @Barmar can you help me by giving me an example please? i was thinking about that too, since every 'array' i find, i will create a "linkable" row to add another pop up for all that data :(

Comment: Try to write it yourself, then someone will help you fix it. I don't have an example handy.

Comment: `typeof key` will return "object" for arrays, thus `typeof key === 'array'` will always be false

Comment: why it will be false for array??? :S

Comment: How to check if an object is an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking `typeof key === 'array'` is incorrect since for arrays `typeof` will return `"object"`. You can try to use `instanceof` instead:

```
if (key instanceof Array) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do another stuff
}
```

But this will fail if your JSON was created in another frame.
Another option is to check `toString()`

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(key).indexOf('Array') > 0
```

or to check

```
Array.isArray(key)
```

but it does not supported by all browsers.

Description of `typeof` you can see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array) for reasons why `instanceof` doesn't always work.

Comment: Bad choice to use indexOf("Array"), what if the object is a Typed Array, eg Int32Array

Comment: @Xotic750 OP mentioned that original object is JSON. According to JSON spec http://www.json.org/ it may contain only plain arrays (not typed)

Comment: I think you will find he is talking about a plain javascript object, like his example, and really not talking about JSON. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation