# JavaScript - identify a property within an array of objects as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I appreciate there are a few questions here already about how to identify an array.  However, I can't find anything regarding identifying an array within an array of objects.

Given the following array:

```
var pagesArray = [{
   category: 'pages1',
   pages: [
       'firstPage1',
       'secondPage1',
       'thirdPage1',
       'fourthPage1']
   }
}];
```

I have tried to loop through and identify that `pages` is also an array like so:

**EDIT**

Actually `o` in the next example should have been `pagesArray` but I've left it as is so that the answers make sense.

```
for(var p in o){     
    console.log(typeof p);
    console.log(p instanceof Array)
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(p))                         
}
```

The output returned for `pages` is:

```
string 
false 
[object String]
```

Is there a way to correctly identify that the property is an array or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: have you tried 'length'?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` on your "array"

Comment: It's not clear what `o` is.

Comment: your answer is here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this answer, I assume your are using a `for..in` loop to iterate over the properties of the object inside `pagesArray`, that is, `pagesArray[0]`.

`for..in` iterates over *keys*, not values. Keys are always strings, so in your loop, `p` is always a string (here, `"categories"`, or `"values"`). To get the value associated with a key, use `o[p]`. You want to test if `o["pages"]` is an array, not if the string `"pages"` is an array.

```
for(var p in o){
    var value = o[p];

    console.log(typeof value);
    console.log(value instanceof Array)
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(value))                         
}
```

Comment: Bingo. This is a common mistake in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`pagesArray[0].pages instanceof Array` works fine, though you have an extra curly brace causing a syntax error.

http://jsfiddle.net/vVPCA/