# How to Parse a Json Object that contains an array within the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my Json Object example:

```
{"UserName":Mike,"IsActive":0,"ChbxIsActive":false,"MyAccountsAvailable":[{"Id":"157A","MyAccount":"CHRIS MCEL","MyCheckBox":false,"Tags":null},{"Id":"157B","MyAccount":"DAN BONE","MyCheckBox":false,"Tags":null}
```

Heres my attempt for part of the object:

```
$.getJSON('/ManageUsers/GetCheckBoxesJson', { clientId: clientId, user: user }, function (data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                alert(key + " " + val);

            });
```

Of course I am successful getting the data from the properties in the object, except not sure how to iterate over the array. I get [Object, Object] If someone could show a sample that would be great.

Comment: update your json object for us, its missing an ending `]` on the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a nested loop to iterate over the array:

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {

    console.log(key + " " + val);

    if(key == 'MyAccountsAvailable') {
        $.each(val, function(subKey, subVal) {
            console.log(subKey + " " + subVal);
        });
    }

});
```

Or directly access the values:

```
console.log( data.MyAccountsAvailable[0].Id );
console.log( data.MyAccountsAvailable[1].Id );
```

Instead of testing for the key name, you could check if the value is an array. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array) for how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help this was the answer I wanted.