# getting a value from an array or a single value

Tags: javascript

I want to extract a value from a variable. If its an array, I want the first element, and if not, I want the value of that variable. The value is a `float`, but I was wondering which of these are better in terms of *performance*, *portability to non-floats*, and of course *short code* and *code readability*

I want to use

```
value = variable[0] || variable
```

Its short and nice, is there any caveats is using this?

or I can do,

```
value = ([].concat(variable))[0]
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array) says it's bad for performance.

And then, ofcourse, I can check if `variable` is an array or not in a few different ways, that is also mentioned in above question. Is there any better ways if the first one is not good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `value = variable[0] || variable` will work, and will work reliably. Technically, if `variable` is a number primitive, what the JS engine has to do at that point is promote it to an object and then look up the `0` property on that object, but as you know it won't have one, that's okay.

The only cases where that may fail are if `variable` is `null` or `undefined`, because neither of those can be promoted to an object, and so the expression will throw. Provided you're okay with that, then you can use that. I'd comment it, though, because it's pretty odd-looking.

If you needed to defend against `null` and `undefined`, you could use the fact that `== null` will filter out both of those:

```
value = variable == null ? undefined : variable[0] || variable;
```

I'd comment that, too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Having this

```
value = variable[0] || variable
```

you may go to a trouble if the first element of the array is false. For example:

```
var arr = [false, 1, 2, 3];
value = variable[0] || variable; // <--- value is [false, 1, 2, 3]
```

So, I'll go with this:

```
var value = arr instanceof Array ? arr[0] : arr;
```

If you are not sure if the array is full then you should add one more check.

```
var value = arr instanceof Array && arr.length > 0 ? arr[0] : arr;
```