# JavaScript - should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I can't find a solution for this question: a function should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. For example "John Smith" should be returned as ["John", "Smith"].

I have:

```
    var myArray = new Array();
    myArray[0] = "John Smith";

    function breakingName() {
      var fullName = myArray[0];
      var splitting = fullName.split(" ");
      return splitting; // not sure why but it doesn't resolve the above challenge 
    }

    myData = new Object();
    myData.fullName = breakingName();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I bet it returns `["John", "Smith"]`. How do you display it?

Comment: This works as expected. How are you determining it does not work correctly?

Comment: If I alert(); it it shows John,Smith

Comment: Because an array stringifies with `.join(',')` by default. Use `console.log` and you'll see a real array that you can inspect.

Comment: Try `alert(JSON.stringify(breakingName())`

Comment: `alert()` only displays strings, so the array is being coerced into one.

Comment: JSON.stringify(breakingName() returned "["John","Smith"]" instead of ["John", "Smith"] ... 
What I have:
function breakingName() {
  var fullName = myArray[0];
  var splitting = fullName.split(" ");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(splitting));
  return splitting;
}

Comment: hope this will help you  'var myArray = ['Md Aminul Hoque' , "gem007bd"];

function cutName(myArray){
  
  return myArray.split(' ');
   
}'

Answer (score 1):

```
"John Smith".split(" "); // gives [ "John", "Smith" ]
```

If you cast it to a string you will *see* `"John,Smith"`, but that's not what it *is*.

Make sure you're using accurate debugging/inspection tools.

Use `console.log` - works great in Firefox and Chrome, not so much in IE.

Do not use `alert` to debug. `alert` takes a string as parameter so everything will be cast to a string. Objects will show up as `[object Object]` rather than `{"foo": "bar"}`

Relevant: [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)

Comment: It still shows that something wrong with it, so the challenge is: breakingName() should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. For example "John Smith" should be returned as ["John", "Smith"]. Do you have any other suggestions? I saw that consol.log worked fine, but not sure why, it didn't resolve this challenge. Thanks for help.

Comment: When I run the code you posted I see `["John", "Smith"]` so it's working as intended.