# javascript string.split(',') makes object when it should make array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

```
var _={};

_.bullets='1,2,3';

console.log(typeof bullets);
```

string

```
console.log(_.bullets);

var bullets=_.bullets.split(',');

console.log(bullets);    //REF 1
```

["1", "2", "3"]

```
console.log(typeof bullets);
```

object

Why is it not array? I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here

***UPDATE***

```
console.log([1,2,3]);
console.log(bullets);    //REF 1
```

[1, 2, 3]

["1", "2", "3"]

What is the difference (one is a string one is a number?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array

Comment: The difference between [1,2,3] and ["1", "2", "3"] is that one is an array with 3 numbers, and one is an array with three strings.

Comment: `typeof [] === "object"` - the only objects where typeof does not yield `"object"` are functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.isArray(a)` or `a instanceof Array`.

Arrays are objects, so `typeof` returns `object`.

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` never returns `'array'`. For instances of `Array`, it returns `'object'`:

**Table 20 — typeof Operator Results**

- Undefined : **"undefined"**
- Null : **"object"**
- Boolean : **"boolean"**
- Number : **"number"**
- String : **"string"**
- Object (native and does not implement [[Call]]) : **"object"**
- Object (native or host and does implement [[Call]]) : **"function"**
- Object (host and does not implement [[Call]]) : **Implementation-defined except may not be "undefined", "boolean", "number", or "string".**

Source: [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)

Answer (score 1):

Technically `typeof` fits for *primitive types* while `instanceof` fits for *reference types*.

If you use `typeof` for some reference types (*Array, Object*), it will return `"object"`. `Function` is the third *reference type*; it behaves differently (`typeof` wise) as it will return `"function"` when `typeof new Function()`.

Based on your example you can deduce that `string` is a *primitive type* in JavaScript as `typeof "blabla" === string` (which returns true). Yes that's something curious if you come from a traditional strongly typed language such as Java or C#.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` returns 'object' when supplied array values. To test for an array you can do something like this (from [JavaScript the Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)):

```
var is_array = function (value) {
     return value &&
     typeof value === 'object' &&
     typeof value.length === 'number' &&
     typeof value.splice === 'function' &&
     !(value.propertyIsEnumerable('length'));
};
```

Comment: This is called duck-typing. If it splices like a duck, it's a duck.