# Why returns Object.keys() an object (looks like array)?

Tags: javascript

I have come across this:

```
var stdin = {123:1,423:1};

var stdout = Object.keys(stdin);

console.log(stdout);             //["123", "423"] 
console.log(typeof(stdout));     //object
console.log(stdout[0])           //123
```

[ECMAScript® Language Specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) says:

> 15.2.3.14 Object.keys ( O )
>
> When the keys function is called with argument O, the following steps are taken:
>
> ... 6. Return *array*.

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/wpVvv/1/

Tested on Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7.

What is going on? Should be array, looks like array to me, *is* Object?

**Edit:**
[typeof()](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3). Arrgh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are objects.

Try typing `typeof([1,2,3])` into your console - you'll also get `object` as the result.

Now, if you type `Object.prototype.toString.call( [1,2,3] )`, you'll get `[object Array]`, which is somewhat useful (and you'll get the same result for the return value of `Object.keys`).

If you want a boolean result, just use `Array.isArray` (see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775737/836214))

Comment: Yeah this is useful. Just wanted to have the output as array and run first time into it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you saying it's an object? Running typeof on an Array will always return 'object'.

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
typeof arr --> "object"
```

Try instead

```
Array.isArray(arr) --> true
```

Here's the test you wanted.

```
var stdin = {123:1,423:1};
Array.isArray(stdin) --> false
```

Comment: OOps, as easy as this? Everything is an object in Javascript, right, hmm? OK: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3. Arrgh. ;) Think this question should run: How does `typeof()` work? Can I delete it please? ;)

Comment: @dollarvar Check out that last minute edit I made. Yeah, it's pretty basic.