# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'filter' IE10

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, filter, dynamics-crm-2011

I load some data from a webservice and try to filter it.

```
var topLevelProductTypes = [];

topLevelProductTypes = productTypesArray.filter(function (pt) {
     return (pt.NS_designcentreproducttypeid.Id === null);
});
```

I get the error SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode? Is `productTypesArray` really an array?

Comment: This code is running on a web resource inside CRM 2011.  I push json data into the productTypesArray using the xrm endpoint for crm.

Comment: >> productTypesArray[0] 
{
 [prototype] : {...},
 __metadata : {...},
 NS_designcentreproducttypeid : {...},
 NS_designcentretypeId : "558b2086-478e-e111-8108-0050568d0006",
 NS_name : "1 Piece Enclosure (Shower)"
} 
Add to watch
>> productTypesArray[0].NS_designcentreproducttypeid.Id 
"15af4efc-468e-e111-8108-0050568d0006" 
>> productTypesArray[0].NS_designcentreproducttypeid 
{
 [prototype] : {...},
 __metadata : {...},
 Id : "15af4efc-468e-e111-8108-0050568d0006",
 LogicalName : "ns_designcentretype",
 Name : "Showers"
} 
Add to watch

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your header `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

And `productTypesArray` looks undeclared in your code. I would assume it is assigned to an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4775722/1959948)

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( productTypesArray) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'It is an array' );
}
```

Comment: fun fact: alert(Object.prototype.toString == toString); saves some keystrokes usually or use ({}).toString to be certain.

Comment: Don’t use `X-UA-Compatible`. Fix the real bug – invalid HTML 99% of the time.

Comment: I ran that check and I get the alert so productTypesArray is in fact an array.

Comment: The same code is working in our dev environment which is a clone of production.

Comment: Yep that didn't fix it either.

Comment: no way :)... there is something clearly wrong with the type then. or on you working on compatibility mode from IE7 or IE8 probably. Those are the only 2 reasons for your issue

Comment: This fixed it for me -but the weird thing was, it *does* work intermittently without this header.  Adding the header simply makes it work reliably. Really odd and I've not come across anything like this before.