# How to check the object is an array or not?

Tags: angularjs

What is the **correct and best** way to check the **object** is **an array** or not ?

```
$scope.studentArray= [{student1},{student2},{student3}];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isArray

```
angular.isArray($scope.studentArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would install [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) and use the [isArray](http://underscorejs.org/#isArray) function like so:

```
_.isArray($scope.studentArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call($scope.studentArray) === '[object Array]') {
  // is array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/)
it uses underscore plus some nice features

syntax is similar/same as underscore

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest solution without any libraries would be:

```
var arr = ['val1','val2','val3'];
console.log(arr instanceof Array); // true

var astring = 'test';
console.log(astring instanceof Array); // false;
```