# get element from arbitrary list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

i have a function in javascript where i need to retrieve the last element of the list. the list can be an array, string, list in numbers (not array). I tried converting the list into a String and then an array and retrieving it by index, but that's not working.

Here is the code I tried:

```
  function last(list){
      var array = new String(list);
      array = array.split("");
      return array[array.length-1];
  }
```

I don't understand what the problem is because test suite says Expected: 5 instead got: 5
I am using code wars and did not write the tests. Is it expecting a Number and getting a String '5' ? I don't understand types in loosely typed languages very well yet.

Comment: `list in numbers (not array)` - What would that be?

Comment: could you post the test?

Comment: @thefourtheye this is one of the tests
Test.assertEquals(last(1,"b",3,"d",5), 5);//-- arguments

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso Here are the tests that are visible to me and it stops running after failing a test so it stops at the first one.

Test.assertEquals(last([1,2,3,4,5]), 5);   //-- array
Test.assertEquals(last("abcde"), "e");     //-- string
Test.assertEquals(last(1,"b",3,"d",5), 5);//-- arguments

Comment: `Is it expecting a Number and getting a String '5' ?` Very possible!

Comment: @user137717 for  `Test.assertEquals(last([1,2,3,4,5]), 5);`, `Test.assertEquals` probably tests with non coercive equality (`===`), so you need to cast it. That said, your other comment makes me think your code isn't the proper solution to the issue. I'm coding an answer now

Answer (score 0):

from the comments, I think you mean you want to either return the last element in an array, the last character in a string, or the last argument passed if multiple arguments were passed. This would do it:

```
function last() {
    if (arguments.length > 1) { // first we handle the case of multiple arguments
        return Array.prototype.pop.call(arguments);
    }
    value = arguments[0]
    if (typeof value === 'string') { // next, let's handle strings
        return value.split('').pop();
    }

    if (Object.prototype.toString.call( [] ) === '[object Array]') {// Arrays are of type object in js, so we need to do a weird check
        return value.pop();
    }
}
```

`arguments` is a pseudo-array that contains all arguments passed into the function, so for `last(1,2,3,4,5)`, `arguments` would be roughly `[1,2,3,4,5]`. It's not exactly that though, because `arguments` has all args in order and a length property, but it's prototype isn't `Array`, so it isn't truly `[1,2,3,4,5]` and lacks all of array's functions. This is why we need to call `pop` in the context of `arguments` (in javascript, `Function.prototype.call` calls the function passing the first arguments as the value of this, and all the rest of the arguments into the `arguments` pseudo-array, so for example `last.call([], 1, 2, 3)` would call `last` in the context of a new array and with `arguments` roughly equal to `[1,2,3]`).

the rest of the code is pretty straightforward, except for the check to see if `value` is an array, which is further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775737/1029988).

Finally, pop is an array method that removes the last element from an array and returns it.