# Can I use `obj.constructor === Array` to test if object is Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, types, prototype

Is it correct to use `obj.constructor === Array` to test if an object is an array as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12268916/483728)? Does it always returns correct answer compatible with `Array.isArray`?

Comment: you can also use the boolean return from "obj instanceof Array", but like your version, it only returns true for an Array of the same window scope.

Comment: Do you have read any of the other answers on that question? http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html

Comment: @Bergi Yes, when I asked this question I was interested to learn more about `obj.constructor === Class` as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends, there are a few scenarios where it can return a different value, but `Array.isArray` will work.

The `Array` object for one window is not the the same `Array` object in another window.

```
var obj = someIframe.contentWindow.someArray;
console.log(obj.constructor === Array);//false
console.log(Array.isArray(obj));//true
```

The `constructor` property can be overwritten.

```
var obj = [];
obj.constructor = null;
console.log(obj.constructor === Array);//false
console.log(Array.isArray(obj));//true
```

Another object can also set the `constructor` property to `Array`.

```
var obj = {};
obj.constructor = Array;
console.log(obj.constructor === Array);//true
console.log(Array.isArray(obj));//false
```

Comment: Also: `var arr = []; arr.__proto__ = Object.create(Array.prototype, {constructor: {value: MyArraySubclass}});`

Comment: Also consider that `obj` could be `undefined`