# How to split an array with retrieved values from DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I've retrieved values from a table, originating from a single column, that I end up storing in an array; but all the data is stored in a single index, and I haven't succeeded in splitting the array with .split.

Step 1 -- I target body and tr.

```
var stuff = document.getElementById('pricetable').querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
```

Step 2 -- I initiate a for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length-1; i++) {
        var rows2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(stuff)[i].querySelectorAll('td')[3];}
```

rows2 will now print a string that looks like this:

```
<td>​2400​</td>​ 
<td>​1900​</td>​
<td>​9790​</td>​
<td>​1098​</td>​
<td>​1289​</td>​
<td>​3284​</td>​
```

I think my problem starts here, since I don't know how to make it into an array and have each of these values stored its own index.

Step 3 -- To retrieve only the text, I create a new variable:

```
var my_list = rows2.textContent;
```

Step 4 -- I then attempt to split the array:

```
var price_list = my_list.split(','));
```

Although price_list is an array (I [verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)), all values remain in price_list[0]. It prints like this:

```
["2400"]
["1900"]
["9790"]
["1098"]
["1289"]
["3284"]
```

If split won't do the trick in this case, do I need to loop through those values? If so, how? Or should I have taken a different course of action? The research that I've done explains how split works with predefined strings that aren't retrieved from the DOM.

Comment: `rows2` is not an array, but a single row. `my_list` is not an array, but a string (that's why you can `.split()` it at all). What you have is a loop over multiple `my_list` strings. Put them in an array using `push`, and then use that after your loop.

Comment: Btw, instead of using `querySelectorAll` you could just have use `.rows[i].cells[3].textContent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is completely unnecessary...

```
var rows2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(stuff)[i].querySelectorAll('td')[3];
```

Also, your variable naming is weird. Why are you calling it `rows2` when you're getting the 4th cell?

To get the fourth cell, just do this:

```
var cell4 = stuff[i].cells[3];
```

---

But if you want an array of those values, then do this instead.

```
var list = Array.prototype.map.call(stuff, function(row) {
    return row.cells[3].textContent;
});
```

This borrows the `.map()` function from `Array.prototype`, which gives you a new array of whatever values you returned from the callback.

---

If this isn't what you want, then you need to describe specifically what it is you're after instead of just showing code that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I was testing a lot and wasn't attentive to variable semantics. Yes, your cell4 variable is better; the list variable, however, gives me an error: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'row.cells[3].textContent')" -- if I remove textContent, the error goes away. Any solutions to that? Also, by using the loop, I can exclude the last row by "i < rows.length-1"; not sure if I can do it in the list variable.

Comment: Do your rows have 4 `<td>` elements each? To exclude the last row, change it to `var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(stuff, 0, -1).map(function(row) {...`

Comment: Wonderful, that did it! I think you forgot to include slice after prototype, that's why I was receiving the error. When I tried your second suggestion, it worked! Thanks for pointing out how to exclude the last row.

Comment: @DanSebastian: `.slice()` is only needed in this case if you want to reduce the set. It works fine with `Array.prototype.map` if you want to include all the rows. There must have been some other issue. Anyway, glad it's working.