# How can I check if value is object in Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this template where I am displaying data in tables:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in tsc.tabEntries" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
  <td ng-repeat="field in tsc.entryFields">{{ obj[field]}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to check that `obj[field]` is an object. If it is, I want to display the `name` property of that object, otherwise the value of `obj[field]`.

How can I do that in template?

Comment: This may help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<td ng-repeat="field in tsc.entryFields">{{ obj[field].name || obj[field] }}</td>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pfeajn3q/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ng-show` for this type of logic in template

```
  <tr ng-repeat="obj in tsc.tabEntries" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
    <span ng-show="obj.field.name">{{obj.field.name}}</span>
    <td ng-repeat="field in tsc.entryFields">{{ obj[field]}}</td>
</tr>
```