# Angular2 equivalent of angular.isArray

Tags: angular

Im playing around with NG2 and I am looking for the equivalent of `angular.isArray`.

Yes, I tried to google it but no luck. Im probably thinking about this problem.

The method I try to use in my ng2-app is this:

```
function periodsFormat(dates, func) {
  if (!angular.isArray(dates)) { return func(dates); }
  return dates.map(func).join('-');
}
```

Surely it should work if I manage to replace `(!angular.isArray...` with something NG2-ish. Thank you!

Update:

Thank you both, I ended doing this:

```
function periodsFormat(dates, func) {
  if (!Array.isArray(dates)) { return func(dates); }
  return dates.map(func).join('-');
}
```

Comment: Do you need an Angular-specific  function?  or can you just use basic  javascript like in the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array

Comment: I probably dont need an angular-specific function. Not sure why I thought so...

Comment: I would have gone with `if (dates instanceof Array) { console.log("it's an array!");}`, but whatever works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you can just check the ctor:

`if (dates.constructor !== Array) { ...`

Since I believe you wouldn't be dealing with possible wrapped objects anymore.

Angular 1 checked for jQuery/jLite array's if I remember correctly which is why there was a special function for checking arrays.