# typeof something return object instead of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

`x` is an array.

I do `console.log(x)` I got

```
[ 'value' ]
```

but when I check the x with type of like `console.log(typeof x)` it says it's an Object. Why?

Comment: When do you initialize your 'x' ?

Comment: Because `array` is of type `object
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if object is array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)

Comment: You should watch out for examples for [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are objects in JS.

If you need to test a variable for array:

```
if (x.constructor === Array)
   console.log('its an array');
```

Comment: first time seeing this!

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN, there is no array type in javascript when using typeof
There is only object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: `typeof` does not always return data type either..for `function(){ }` it will return `function` but there is no data type as `function`..

Answer (score 2):

if your purpose is to check, the "is it Array or not" ? you better use

```
Array.isArray()
```

The Array.isArray() method returns true if an object is an array, false if it is not.  [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

so you can try

```
if(typeof x === 'object' &&  Array.isArray(x)) {
    //Its an array
}
```

UPDATE:
Array is an object, so `typeof x` reports its an object. but then why on earth `typeof function` reports it correctly!!! ?  **Good question** . **take good care while using `typeof`**

Answer (score 0):

Array is an Object type, so it's fine !

Answer (score 0):

X is an Array defined in global scope. So, when you do console.log(x), you are able to see

```
 ['value']
```

Also, refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) for details about JavaScript data types which says,

**Arrays are regular objects for which there is a particular relationship between integer-key-ed properties and the 'length' property**

Hence the type return as **Object** is correct and as expected.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't "Array" type in javascript

```
 typeof ['1'];//object
 typeof {};//object
 typeof null;//object
```

other often used value type:

```
 number,string,undefined,boolean,function
```

Answer (score 0):

The typeof operator threw me off a couple times before I discovered that arrays, null, and objects will all return as 'object'.  I threw together this quick and dirty function that I now use in place of typeof - which still returns a string indicating the variable type:

```
TestType = (variable) => {
  if(Array.isArray(variable)){
    return 'array'
  }
  else if(variable === null){ //make sure to use the triple equals sign (===) as a double equals sign (==) will also return null if the variable is undefined
    return 'null'
  }else{
    return typeof variable
  }
}
```