# Initializing an array in Javascript returns an object

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var tempList = []
// or
var tempList = new Array()
```

when I test what it is, it returns an object. How can I initialize it as an array and why is this weird error occurring?

```
console.log(typeof tempList); // object
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array

Comment: If you want an array, then initialize by --  var tempList = new Array(); What you have done, creates a new object only.

Comment: I am still getting object??

Comment: Maybe it has to be said that I am trying to add objects into the array. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Actually http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp , says what I said is wrong and what you did initially was correct.  So revert back.  Does this 'typeof ' thing really matter?

Comment: Yes cause the function .push() does not work.. which only holds for arrays.

Comment: edit the question and share a little more of the code that causes error.