# For Each loop ---> For loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am having a error that states that data.forEach is not a function. The code is:

```
function getProperGeojsonFormat(data) {
    isoGeojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []};

    console.log("After getProperGeojsonFormat function")
    console.log(data)
    console.log("")

    data.forEach(function(element, index) {
        isoGeojson.features[index] = {};
        isoGeojson.features[index].type = 'Feature';
        isoGeojson.features[index].properties = element.properties;
        isoGeojson.features[index].geometry = {};
        isoGeojson.features[index].geometry.coordinates = [];
        isoGeojson.features[index].geometry.type = 'MultiPolygon';

        element.geometry.geometries.forEach(function(el) {
            isoGeojson.features[index].geometry.coordinates.push(el.coordinates);
        });
    });
    $rootScope.$broadcast('isochrones', {isoGeom: isoGeojson});



}
```

The error I am getting is:

[image]

When I console log data:

[image: When I console log data]

Comment: it depends on whether data is an array or not.

Comment: a [mcve] would be great!

Comment: They have already helped you

Comment: @SamuelToh my response is a JSON

Comment: JSON in JS is a string. Strings in JS do not have a `forEach` method.

Comment: I think OP means that his data is an object (classic confusion between JSON and objects).

Comment: @zerkms so I have to change to a For Loop ?

Comment: JSON can represent an object or an array. It appears that this JSON represents an object.

Comment: To tell if something is an array, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array. That link also shows you how to turn a single object *into* an array containing that object, if that's what you want.

Comment: @Mr.KGK no you don't. Using `for` over strings also makes very little sense.

Comment: You have `console.log(data)` -- can't you tell by looking at it whether it's an array or not? If it's an array it will have `[]` around it.

Comment: @Barmar Pls advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an object. It looks like you want to loop over the `features` array within that object, so do:

```
data.features.forEach(function(element, index) {
    isoGeojson.features[index] = {
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: element.properties,
        geometry: {
            type: 'MultiPolygon',
            coordinates: element.coordinates.slice()
        }            
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to change data.features.forEach. Now i have a issue with the next forEach

Comment: Apologies, but it back there

Comment: Stop putting the answer into the question. I've put back the original question.

Answer (score 0):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) works on arrays, not on objects. It seems here that `data` is an object.

Use this instead.

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(index) {
    var element = data[index];
    isoGeojson.features[index] = {};
    isoGeojson.features[index].type = 'Feature';
    isoGeojson.features[index].properties = element.properties;
    isoGeojson.features[index].geometry = {};
    isoGeojson.features[index].geometry.coordinates = [];
    isoGeojson.features[index].geometry.type = 'MultiPolygon';

    element.geometry.geometries.forEach(function(el) {
        isoGeojson.features[index].geometry.coordinates.push(el.coordinates);
    });
});
```

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) creates an array from the keys of an object. You can then iterate over these keys and fetch the associated value.
This approach will work on any objects.