# Is there anyway to know specific type of javascript variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have variable `data` below

```
var data = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    sex: "M",
    maritalStatus: "M",
    dob:"01-01-1990",
    title:"Software Engineer",
    address:"VN",
    phoneNumber:"(123) 456-7890",
    email: "john@gmail.com"
}
];

var data = [
    ["1", "John", "M", "M", "1990", "Software Engineer", "john@gmail.com", "(123) 456-7890"],
];
```

Is there anyway to know their type.I'm using `typeof(data)` but both show it's object.

Comment: Arrays are objects in Javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array

Comment: `isArray()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: `typeof` lies lots of times, but here it's correct. `data` belongs to Object type.

Comment: There are a lot of hacks depending on what you are trying to achieve, e.g. `data.constructor.name`. But it's better to use "feature detection" like `isArray(data)` and act accordigly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.isArray(data)` will return true since data is an array.

**EDIT:**

After clarification in the comments of this answer, `Array.isArray(data[0])` will check if the first element in the array data is an array.

Comment: I have try that one but both data return true

Comment: Array.isArray(data) should return true since data is an array.

Comment: Both is an array.The first one is object object,Second on is object Array

Comment: Oh so you are wanting the first one to return false and the second to return true?

Comment: yes @Charlie Fish.How can I achived that

Comment: Ok sorry didn't quite understand your question. As long as it's the first element you are wanting to check "Array.isArray(data[0])" without the quotes should work. I will also edit my question now to reflect that. BUT it has to be the first element you are wanting to check. That will basically check to see if the first element inside of data is an array.

Comment: Thanks Charlie and also sorry for my bad language :D

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc It's totally ok! Glad I could help in the end!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Object.prototype.toString().call(object)

```
var data = 
{
 id: 1,
 name: "John",
 sex: "M",
 maritalStatus: "M",
 dob:"01-01-1990",
 title:"Software Engineer",
 address:"VN",
 phoneNumber:"(123) 456-7890",
 email: "john@gmail.com"
};

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(data) ); //[object Object]


var data2 = [
{
 id: 1,
 name: "John",
 sex: "M",
 maritalStatus: "M",
 dob:"01-01-1990",
 title:"Software Engineer",
 address:"VN",
 phoneNumber:"(123) 456-7890",
 email: "john@gmail.com"
}
];


console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(data2) ); //[object Array]

var data1 = [
               ["1", "John", "M", "M", "1990", "Software Engineer", "john@gmail.com", "(123) 456-7890"],
            ];

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(data1) );//[object Array]
```