# How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have  the following structure in JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":"79",
      "value":"val1"
   },
  {
      "id":"88",
      "value":["val1","val2","new"]
  }
]
```

How to handle this cases? I've tried this but  it only handle the first case:

```
<?php
$arr = json_decode($json_string);
$itemsList = new stdClass;

$i_d=0;
foreach ($arr as $key=>$arrj):
    $itemsList->id[$i_d]    = $arrj->id;
    $itemsList->value[$i_d] = $arrj->value;
    $i_d++;
endforeach;
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to handle when value atrribute has only simple value and the case when has a array as value

Comment: Rene, please explain more precisely what you mean by "handle". Your code does handle any type of value; it is simply stored in `$itemsList->value[$i_d]`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Use the property's type as a condition [in an `if` statement or other conditional statement].  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your foreach loop, you can check that `$arrj->value` is an array. If it is, you can loop over it and add its values into your result object one by one, and if it isn't, you can add the single value as you already are.

```
<?php
$arr = json_decode($json_string);

$itemsList = new stdClass;

foreach ($arr as $key=>$arrj):
    $itemsList->id[] = $arrj->id;

    if (is_array($arrj->value)) {            // Is it an array?
        foreach ($arrj->value as $value) {   // If so, add its values in a loop
            $itemsList->value[] = $value;
        }
    } else {
        $itemsList->value[] = $arrj->value;  // if not, just add the single value
    }
endforeach;
?>
```

I removed the `$i_d` variable; it is unnecessary because PHP will automatically create numeric indices beginning with 0 when you add values to an array using `[]`.

Comment: yes, it solves this problem, but in my case was neccesary to use index for other reasons