# How to safely wrap an object into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a function that takes in an `Array`, iterates over it finding all `Objects` and displays them to the UI.

In rare cases, I have to supply an `Object` (result from a `WS` as `application/JSON`) which is not an `Array` by default and hence my function fails to iterate over it and display on the UI.

In normal cases my `Array` looks like this:

```
[
  { "name" : "foo"},
  { "name" : "bar"},
  { "name" : "baz"}
]
```

and this works like it is supposed to. However, sometimes the data I get could be this:

```
{ "name" : "I am not in a List"}
```

and my function that takes in an array looks like this:

```
function loadJSONIntoUI(data) {

    for (var aMsg = 0; aMsg < data.length(); aMsg++) {
        // Do something with each `index` in the List
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can detect that the single object which is not an array is an odd one and probably put it into a List on the fly and pass it to a function?

So far I have tried to use `typeof` and also tried to create a new `Array` on the fly and `push` my object into it but it prints out a `1` when I do that.

Comment: Is the single item inside an array? If not you can just check if the[variable is an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array). If it is you can check if `array.length == 1`.

Comment: Its not a list, its an array... And in js they are a special kind of object, so if you write object methods they also work for an array

Comment: `List` is called _array_ in JavaScript. Also `JSON` is _text data_ - since it stands for "JavaScript Object Notation", then if it's already in JavaScript, it's an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can transform it in an array if is not and let iterate one time:

```
function loadJSONIntoUI(data) {

    if(!(data instanceof Array)){
       data = [data];
    }

    for (var aMsg = 0; aMsg < data.length; aMsg++) {
        // Do something with each `index` in the List
    }
}
```

Also, length doesn't need to be called like a method.

Let me know if it works

Cheers

Comment: would be better if the condition is like `(supportedLongs instanceof Array) === false`

Answer (score 44):

A one liner using [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
[couldBeArray].flat()
```

Examples:

```js
const anObj = {name: "Hi"};
const anArr = [{name: "Hi"}];

const wrapped1 = [anObj].flat() 
const wrapped2 = [anArr].flat() 

console.log(wrapped1);  // wrapped1 is [{name: "Hi"}]
console.log(wrapped2);  // wrapped2 is [{name: "Hi"}]
```

Answer (score 21):

You can simply use `Array.concat()` to auto-wrap an object into an array:

```js
const obj = {name: "foo"};
const arr = [{name: "bar"}];

const result1 = [].concat(obj); // result1 is [{name: "foo"}]
const result2 = [].concat(arr); // result2 is [{name: "bar"}]

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: This is a safer option than using .flat() as it works for both objects and single values. eg:
Both 
`const item1 = "string";` and 
`const item2 = {value: "string"};` 
Will safely return 

`const result = [].concat(item1); // still works and returns ["string"]` and 
`const result = [].contact(item2); // still works and returns [{value:"string" }]`

Answer (score 5):

[Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) can be used to achieve what you need:

```
function loadJSONIntoUI(data) {
    if(!Array.isArray(data)) {
        data = [data];
    }
    for (var aMsg = 0; aMsg < data.length(); aMsg++) {
        // Do something with each `index` in the List
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: This only works in IE9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for an array and fix an error - should be just `data.length`, no brackets. See code below, check demo - https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/fgedaubm/

```
function loadJSONIntoUI(data) {
    var data = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [ data ];
    for (var aMsg = 0; aMsg < data.length; aMsg++) {
        // Do something with each `index` in the List
        console.log(data[aMsg]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Again: FYI: This only works in IE9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Answer (score -1):

You can use Array.of(). So in your case `Array.of(data)` returns `[{ "name" : "I am not in a List"}]`

Comment: This answer is incorrect - it produces a nested array.