# jQuery check if not null/undefined/empty with != doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, logical-operators

I have this jQuery code

```
if (date != !date) {
    console.log(date);
}
```

The `date` is an array, or `null`. If it's an array, I want to log it, if it is `null` I want to stop it right there. I thought the `!= !var` was exactly for this purpose. Still when I try this, I do also get `null` console logs. How come?

Comment: Try `date != null`. `x != !x` will always be `true`.

Comment: @JF - so obvious, so simple.

Comment: To expand on what J F said, consider this scenario: `true != !true` -> `true != false` -> `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should catch everything in the else...

```
if(Array.isArray(date)){
  console.log(date); 
}
else {
  console.log('not array');
}
```

Comment: This is good, it fits perfectly as my var should always be an array and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks @AlexTimmer - literally hundreds of ways you can do this - this just seemed to be the most verbose. To be honest you don't even need the else statement, depends on if you want to catch it or not.

Answer (score 2):

x is always not equal to !x (this is what `x!= !x` means).

You want something like : does x exist ? Is it null ?

```
if (date != null) {
    console.log(date);
}
```

```js
var x1;
var x2 = [1,2];

if(x1 != null) // <- false
   console.log(x1); 

if(x2 != null) // <- true
  console.log(x2);
```

Comment: I wanted to catch all possible outcomes (null, undefined etc), but I guess `!= null` will do.

Comment: @AlexTimmer `!= null` will be `true` for both `undefined` and `null`, but `!== null`  will be `true` for `null` only.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (date){
    console.log(date);
}
```

Comment: what is `strlen`?

Comment: strlen return the number of characters

Comment: In JavaScript? And in an array?

Comment: UPS :) it was PHP. In javascript:

if (date.length  > 1) {
    console.log(date);
}

Answer (score -2):

So you need to find out whether some value is an array or not. Here is another way to do this as recommended by the ECMAScript standard. For more infos about this see this post: [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)

```js
var date = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var txt = "bla ... bla ...";

if( Object.prototype.toString.call( date ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    console.log('is array');
} else {
    console.log(' not an array');
}

if( Object.prototype.toString.call( txt ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    console.log('is array');
} else {
    console.log('is not an array');
}
```