# How to check if value is an array and then get first element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem with representing of my values in my `html table`. I have `array` of values, most of them are `strings`, but while program works some of these become `arrays`. Something like I have here:

```
if(res.data.results[elem]['value'].toLowerCase() === nextProps.value){
    res.data.results[elem]['value'] = [res.data.results[elem]['value'], 'black'];
    res.data.results[elem]['another_value'] = [res.data.results[elem]['another_value'], 'black'];
}
```

I try to flag it with colors as you checked already. And then I print them in `table`, as I managed already, in this way:

```
<td style={{'color': result['value'][1]}}>{result.value[0]}</td>
<td style={{'color': result['another_value'][1]}}>{result.another_value[0]}</td>
```

When I have only `string` in my value I get first letter of my word/sentence/whatever. Is there another way to print whole `string` when value is not an `array` instead of making `arrays` from all values at the start?

Comment: you want to check the value is array of not correct?

Comment: you have methods like `isArray()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray - you can use simple check like `result['value'].isArray() ? result['value'][0] : result['value']`

Comment: But I wanna to do it in my style if it's possible and then take first element if true and whole string if false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use simple check like

```
Array.isArray(result['value']) ? result['value'][0] : result['value']
```

edited the way of use this function