# Object and array processing code not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function called `maybeNoises` to test if an array has noises or not and then to print them to the console.

The prompt is as follow:

```
Function should take an object, if this object has a noises array return them as a string separated by a space, if there are no noises return 'there are no noises' (2, 1, 3)
```

This is my code:

```
function maybeNoises(object) {
  if (object.noises) {
    return object.noises.join(" ");
  } else if (object["noises"].isArray(undefined)) {
    console.log("THIS TEST IS STUPID AND PISSING ME OFF");
  } else(object["noises"].isArray(null));
  return 'there are no noises';
}
```

This is what it is testing:

> QUnit.test("maybeNoises() : Should take an object, if this object has a noises array return them as a string separated by a space, if there are no noises return 'there are no noises'",

```
function(assert) {
  assert.equal(maybeNoises({
    noises: ["bark", "woof", "squeak", "growl"]
  }), "bark woof squeak growl");
  assert.equal(maybeNoises({
    noises: []
  }), "there are no noises");
  assert.equal(maybeNoises({}), "there are no noises");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `object["noises"].isArray(undefined)` what the heck is this supposed to be doing

Comment: an Array does not have a `.isArray` property ... you're thinking of `Array.isArray(object.noises)`

Comment: I put object["noises"].isArray(undefined) to test the condition for an empty array. I'm assuming I didn't do it right in regard to your wording expression.

Comment: an empty Array is tested by `object.noises.length === 0` once `object.noises` has been determined to be an Array

Comment: `else(object["noises"].isArray(null));` isn't valid javascript syntax either

Comment: function-master.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at maybeNoises (function-master.js:113)
    at Object.<anonymous> (function-master.html?notrycatch:77)
    at Test.run (qunit-1.19.0.js:804)
    at qunit-1.19.0.js:942
    at process (qunit-1.19.0.js:624)
    at begin (qunit-1.19.0.js:606)
    at qunit-1.19.0.js:666

Comment: that's the error message I get when I set the expression to test against object.noises.length ===0

Comment: what is `object` when you get that error? your whole logic is reverse order to what it should be

Comment: Object is undefined

Comment: Well I'm trying to get the logic down. What it is that I'm actually suppose to be doing if I'm doing completely the opposite.

Comment: if object is `undefined` then of course it doesn't have a property called length

Comment: `const maybeNoises = object => Array.isArray(object.noises) && object.noises.join(' ') || 'there are no noises';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues with your code are

1. `else(object["noises"].isArray(null))` isn't valid syntax
2. `if (object.noises) return object.noises.join(" ");` - your first test assumes that `object` has a property named `noises`, and that this `noises` object has a property called `join` which is a `function` ... that's a lot to assume without testing!!! ... what if noises is `true` for example, `true` doesn't have a join property! What if object is null/undefined? It doesn't even have a property called noises!
3. `object["noises"].isArray(undefined)` an array doesn't have a `isArray` function, only `Array` (literally, Array, not "an Array") has that function, and the argument to it should be the object you want to test

So, here's all you need to do

```
function maybeNoises(object) {
// we know nothing about object yet, so lets not assume
    if (object && object.noises) { // check that object and object.noises are "something"
        // here, we know that object.noises is "something" 
        if (Array.isArray(object.noises)) { // check that object.noises is an Array
            // here we know that object.noises is an array, so, it has a length
            if (object.noises.length > 0) { // check length is > 0
                return object.noises.join(' ');
            }
        }
    }
    return 'there are no noises'; // didn't pass the above tests, so return this string
}
```

Comment: *"`else(object["noises"].isArray(null))` isn't valid syntax"* - Sure it is. It just doesn't do at all what the OP wants.

Comment: yeah, that @nnnnnn :p

Comment: You're psuedocode helped a lot. I understand now more how I should have approached the issue and where my flawed logic was, which is what I wanted more than the answer. I'm a total coding newb so all these concepts kinda assaulted me at once and I have trouble navigating through it a bit. Thank you for explaining it to me.

Comment: that's not psuedocode, that's how you should actually re-write  your code

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer to summarize all the problems:

1.) Check if there is a noises array.

You wanna do `Array.isArray(object.noises)` or if you are in the unlikely event of this not working in your javascript implementation you can check for other alternatives here: [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)

2.) Check if the array has elements:
`object.noises.length` can be used to see if the array has any entries.

3.) Return the noises as array
You figured that out already correctly.

Comment: `A proper test` - would be `Array.isArray(object.noises)` since about 2010 (even IE9)

Comment: Yes that alternative is also listed in the linked answers. But it wouldnt work with `undefined` as argument ;)

Comment: really? so `Array.isArray(undefined)` does what?

Comment: I know. I updated my answer to clearify the different options.

Comment: I already know it's an array. What is not passing, is that I have a second test  that is testing against an empty array (undefined) and I am trying to put an appropriate else if statement to test against that.

Comment: What do you wanna test with isArray(undefined) the isArray function does not take any arguments. Check the documentation of it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray