# "If is array.... then" but in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I am using `Tampermonkey` for writing scripts. Before i was using AUTOIT, and there was a function like "If is array then". Is there any option like this in JavaScript?

The main command is

```
>     setTimeout(function (){
> 
> document.querySelector('[value="Click"]').click();
> 
>     }, 999);
```

I want to click in that class(and more)

```
<div class="center" onclick="58246246.submit()" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

I try something like that but it doesn't work, script is clicking in first value

```
if ($("center")[0]){
setTimeout(function (){
$1(function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("center")[0].click();
        }, 999);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) checks for array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if object is array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)

Comment: `a function like "If is array then". Is there any option like this in javascript` - Yes and if you google for `how to check if is array in JavaScript` you find an answer very very very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.isArray(object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) is what you're looking for. It returns true if the object is an array, false otherwise. Checking the documentation you can see exactly what the limits to this are (for example, `Array.prototype` is an array).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Array.isArray(array_name);`

```
if(Array.isArray(array_name){
    if ($("center")[0]){
        setTimeout(function (){
            $1(function(){
                document.getElementsByClassName("center")[0].click();
            }, 999);
}
```