# Array parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How I can to define array parameter in javascript function. For example in c# I can just like this.

```
private void myFunc(params object[] values){

}
```

Comment: it's just like function myfunc(myArray){/**/}

Comment: You want to specify that a particular argument passed to a function is, by default, an Array?

Comment: In javascript you cant specify parameter type, simply do `var func = function(array){}` And then you have to take care that `array` is of type `Array`. http://no.gd/p/untyped-20120205-235300.jpg

Comment: There is huge data around to find out. Google it

Comment: I'd like to call function like this myFunc("1","2","n") and retrieve data in function via foreach()

Comment: Ok, so this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). *Ask about your real problem, not about the supposed solution*. If you want to pass in an array, then pass an array, not three separate values. `myFunc( ["1","2","n"] )`

Comment: JJJ, ok I See. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is dynamically typed. Any argument can be passed an array. There is no special syntax to declare it.

```js
function example(my_argument) {
    if (my_argument instanceof Array) {
       console.log(my_argument, "is an array");
    } else {
       console.log(my_argument, "is not an array");
    }
}

example([1,2,3]);
example("a string");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify type of argument in Javascript, it's dynamically typed language. In case you want to check explicitly type of argument then you can do something like:

```
function(arg1) {
    if (typeof arg1 !== 'object') {
        throw new Error('Invalid type of argument');
    }
}
```

Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array).