# Javascript zip jQuery arrays into one

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript where I parse data attributes from DOM objects.
I want to zip those two arrays into one, so I get a multidimensional (in this case 2D) array with `[[id1, atr1], [id2, atr2], ...]`
However, this code below gives me a 1D array with all the ids followed by all the attributes.

I als tried to use `map(element, index)` producing the same result.
Can someone help me to zip this correctly?

```
var currentHTML = $('.product');
var currentId = $("body").find('.product').toArray().map(function(e){return $(e).attr("data-id-product");});    
var currentAtr = $("body").find('.product').toArray().map(function(e){return $(e).attr("data-id-product-attribute");}); 
currentHTMLMap = [];

for(i = 0;i < currentId.length; i++) {
    currentHTMLMap.push(currentId[i], currentAtr[i]);
}
```

Here is how the two 1D arrays could look like:

```
currentId: ["1", "6"]
currentAtr: ["1", "0"]
```

Screenshot of my console showing the jQuery 'created' arrays:

[image]

Comment: `currentHTMLMap.push([currentId[i], currentAtr[i]]);`

Comment: this still produces 1,1,6,0 :/

Comment: with Underscore.JS you could use `_.zip(currentId, currentAtr)`.

Comment: It shouldnt, see it implemented in answer below

Comment: I added a screenshot of my console showing the two jQuery arrays that should be merged

Comment: do you want [1,6,1,0,...] as result ? sorry i didn't understand what you want as output

Comment: No, I want to get a 2D array of [id, atr] like [[1,1], [6,0]]

Comment: You can shorten your entire code (including this question) down to `var currentHTMLMap = $('.product').toArray().map(elm => [
  $(elm).attr("data-id-product"),
  $(elm).attr("data-id-product-attribute")
]);`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Will includes work if I have another 2D array of the same 'type'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) which takes `element1[, ...[, elementN]]` and push them all to the end of the array. You need to push **a new array** with both elements within. To fix that write `currentHTMLMap.push([currentId[i], currentAtr[i]]);` (note the extra brackets that wrap the two elements).
However, you could also use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is more elegant.

```js
var currentId = ["1", "6"];
var currentAtr = ["1", "0"];
var currentHTMLMap = currentId.map(function(e, i) {
  return [e, currentAtr[i]]
});

console.log(currentHTMLMap); // [[1,1], [6,0]]
```

---

By the way, looking your whole example, you could simply do this:
**Important to use double brackets since jQuery unwrap the first brackets.**

```js
var currentHTMLMap = $('.product').map(function(i, e) {
  var $element = $(e);
  return [
    [$element.attr("data-id-product"), $element.attr("data-id-product-attribute")]
  ];
}).toArray();

console.log(currentHTMLMap); // [[1,1], [6,0]]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product" data-id-product="1" data-id-product-attribute="1">
</div>
<div class="product" data-id-product="6" data-id-product-attribute="0">
</div>
```

Comment: I did that myself too, but I get no zipped array. See my screenshot of my jQuery arrays in the console, maybe I am missing something

Comment: when I do typeof currentHTMLMap I get object

Comment: `typeof currentHTMLMap` will return `object` for an array :) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956445/1918287) is how you check if object is an array

Answer (score 0):

consider the follwing:

```
let arr = [];
let arr1 = ["a","b"];
let arr2 = ["c","d"];

for(i = 0;i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr.push([arr1[i], arr2[i]]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

will produce:

> [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd' ] ]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this, but you could pull in a library called Ramda

```html
<span class="product" data-id-product="1" data-id-product-attribute="foo"></span>
<span class="product" data-id-product="2" data-id-product-attribute="bar"></span>

<script>
  // globally define DOM variables
  const products = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.product'));
  const currentIds = products.map(e => e.dataset.idProduct);    
  const currentAtrs = products.map(e => e.dataset.idProductAttribute); 
</script>

<!-- import a single function for modern browsers -->
<script type="module">
  import zip from 'https://unpkg.com/ramda@0.25.0/es/zip.js?module';
  const currentHTMLMap = zip(currentIds, currentAtrs)
  console.log(currentHTMLMap)
</script>

<!-- load the minified bundle for old browsers -->
<script nomodule src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha256-YN22NHB7zs5+LjcHWgk3zL0s+CRnzCQzDOFnndmUamY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script nomodule>
  const currentHTMLMap = R.zip(currentIds, currentAtrs);
  console.log(currentHTMLMap)
</script>
```