# What is the main difference between array and object in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects, declaration

The point of confusion is - when we check the type of array or object using  `typeof` get the return value as Object. So what's the main difference between them.

Comment: Arrays are objects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-an-array

Answer (score 0):

You can check using constructor.name

```js
const myArr = []
const myObj = {}


console.log(`myArr is an ${myArr.constructor.name}`)
console.log(`my Obj is an ${myObj.constructor.name}`)
```

Comment: That really is not the *main* difference.