# test case failing due to .map is not a function error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, enzyme

Hi i have a react component **expenses-total.js** and a corresponding test case **expenses-total.test.js** as shown below.

expenses-total.js

```
     export default (expenses=[]) => {
      if (expenses.length === 0) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return expenses
          .map(expense => expense.amount)
          .reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0);
      }
    };
```

expenses-total.test.js

```
import selectExpensesTotal from '../../selectors/expenses-total';
const expenses = [
    {
      id: "1",
      description: "gum",
      amount: 321,
      createdAt: 1000,
      note: ""
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      description: "rent",
      amount: 3212,
      createdAt: 4000,
      note: ""
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      description: "Coffee",
      amount: 3214,
      createdAt: 5000,
      note: ""
    }
  ];

test('Should return 0 if no expenses', ()=>{
    const res = selectExpensesTotal([]);
    expect(res).toBe(0);
});

test('Should correctly add up a single expense', ()=>{
    const res = selectExpensesTotal(expenses[0]);
    expect(res).toBe(321);
});

test('Should correctly add up multiple expenses',()=>{
    const res = selectExpensesTotal(expenses);
    expect(res).toBe(6747);
});
```

when i run the test case, its getting failed by giving an error

```
TypeError: expenses.map is not a function
```

I know the test case is correct but dont know what is wrong with thecomponent.
Could anyone please help me in fixing this error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `if (expenses.length === 0)` and the test case that uses `selectExpensesTotal(expenses[0])`:

`expenses[0]` passes an object, which has no `length` property, so in the function being tested, `expenses.length` returns `undefined`. However, `undefined === 0` evaluates to `false` so your code goes into the `else` block tries to use `.map` on the object, which doesn't have that function, thus it throws an error.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, what would be the alternate option to get this done?

Comment: @ShivakumarH.G Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-an-array) for options.

Answer (score 0):

In a brief: **you can't map over an object**.

`expenses` is an array of objects, so `expenses[0]` is an object.

Condition  `expenses.length === 0` evaluates to `false`, since obviously `.length` property **does not exist** on `Object.prototype`, so the `else` condition takes place - your function tries to `map` over an object.

Comment: Just to clarify, `.length` doesn't exist on *this* object, but it most certainly **can** exist on objects (just not by default).

Comment: @Herohtar Agreed, `Object.prototype` is much more accurate term.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that expenses[0] is an object (you probably expected it to be an array) and an object does not have a map function. A quick hack would be to add another ifs into the loop to check if expenses is actually an object. So that:

```
export default (expenses=[]) => {
  if (expenses.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    if (typeof expenses === 'object') {
      return expenses.amount
    } else {
    return expenses
      .map(expense => expense.amount)
      .reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0);
    }
  }
};
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you can pass in an array of object into

```
selectExpensesTotal([expenses[0]])
```

rather than just an object

```
selectExpensesTotal(expenses[0])
```

So your code show look like this:

```
test('Should correctly add up a single expense', ()=>{
    const res = selectExpensesTotal([expenses[0]]);
    expect(res).toBe(321);
});
```

`.map` function will now work on expenses. Because, this is now an `array of object ( works with map function )` and not an `object(This does not work with map function)`