# How can I find an object in an object array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, hashmap

Here's an obj.

```
var person = {
    no: 4,
    name: "Jack",
    hobbies:["soccer, dancing"],
    club: "lion"
}
```

Here's object arraies.

```
var club = {
    no: 2,
    name: "lion",
    teacher: "Linda",
    num: 24
    students: [person, person2, person3, ...]
}

var school = {
    no: "NW-10",
    name: "The school of Victory",
    address: "23 Vega St. Gorgia, Texas",
    classes: [club, club2, club3, ...]
}
```

I'd like to find a class in the school. School is only one. And Class, Person are multiple.

And I'd like to add, remove, edit `school` it belongs to and the `class`.

Is there any way to find an object with an index? I mean like a HashMap. You access a value with a string like this.

```
var mAge = mPerson["age"];
var mAge = mPerson.age;
```

I can find the object with for loop but, the login seems very complicated and not efficient as much as O(n^2).

## Edit

I'd like to accomplish `get`, `put`, `remove`, `edit` in an array with Object.

For example,

I want to remove `person3`. Then, I can find its class like this.

```
school[person.club].remove(); // The club item is removed.

school2[person.club].put(2); // The club item is added after second club object.
```

It will find the item in O(n).

Comment: Your objects are invalid JavaScript. This is incorrect: `hobbies:{"soccer, dancing"}`.

Comment: either this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript?rq=1 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-array?rq=1

Comment: you can use array.find

Comment: Could you add more details on what you are trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Create like `students: [person, person2, person3, ....]`

Comment: @Teemu in the object.

Comment: @Teemu I know `class` can't be used, This is just an example how they look like.

Comment: @giuseppedeponte I added more information.

Comment: @GlenK I added more information about my question. Could you answer it?

Comment: Now after your edit, the question is clear, but far too broad considering you haven't tried anything. I'd suggest you an OOP approach, create a prototype/class of the objects, add the methods you need to that, and an object factory to create new objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific functionality, I would create a function for it. For example you can create removeClub function and putClub function:

```
var person = {
    no: 4,
    name: "Jack",
    hobbies:["soccer, dancing"],
    club: "lion"
};

var club = {
    no: 2,
    name: "lion",
    teacher: "Linda",
    num: 24,
    students: [person]
}

var school = {
    no: "NW-10",
    name: "The school of Victory",
    address: "23 Vega St. Gorgia, Texas",
    classes: [club]
};

function removeClub(clubName){
  var clubIndex = school.classes.findIndex(c => c.name === clubName);
  school.classes.splice(clubIndex, 1);
}

function putClub(clubName, index){
  school.classes.splice(index, 0, clubName);
}

removeClub(person.club);
putClub(person.club,0);
console.log(school);
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it in `O(1)`?

Comment: I tried this method and I don't know if an object works as well. I did `slice(index, 1)` to remove the Object element and It is not removed.