# How to understand Symbol.toStringTag or @@toStringTag?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) and [ES6 specs definition of Symbol.toStringTag](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols) but don't quite get what it means.  Is it supposed to be thought of as:

1. If the `toString()` method of an object or a class is defined, then the `@@toStringTag` is irrelevant. (Unless if the self-defined `toString()` uses `@@toStringTag`, but in what way?)
2. Otherwise, `Object`'s `toString()` will use the function referred to by `[Symbol.toStringTag]` to obtain an object name to display as `[Object XYZ]`

?

Comment: It's related to the ancient way of `Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date) === "[object Date]"`, and accordingly `Object.prototype.toString.call({ [Symbol.toStringTag]: "myNiceName" }) === "[object myNiceName]"`

Comment: Be aware that `@@toStringTag` is not a function, but a string. In contrast to `toString`...

Comment: There were (are?) some legacy uses for this, e.g. [how to check if an object is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-array), before `Array.isArray`, or other weird runtime type checks. That's because `Object.prototype.toString` [checks internal properties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring), and was (is?) the only way to check certain things.

Comment: @trincot because I saw `class ValidatorClass {
  get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    return 'Validator';
  }
}` it looked like there was a `return` involved but it is not a function?

Comment: Ah, you are right, it can be a getter. It is accessed as a string property, not called as a function -- although a getter *is* of course called; it is a syntax difference.

Comment: @nopole for some weird reason, documentation around `@@toStringTag` usually shows using it as a getter. Not sure why since it seems like just extra overhead for trying to understand the concept. Basically, getters are accessed like properties. If you have `obj = {get foo() { return "bar" }}` then `obj.foo == "bar"` and `obj.foo()` is a TypeError because you're doing `"bar"()`. I can only guess they are using a getter since you can't reassign it as a normal property (without a setter).

Comment: @VLAZ I guess the weird reason is that most documentation at the same time tries to show off an ES6 class, where plain-value prototype properties cannot be declared.