# How to test if a variable is an array of a certain type of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, types

I have an object. Let us call it `foo`. I want `bar` (a function, or another object, doesn't really matter) to take an array of `foo`. I also want to make sure that it is indeed getting that, so I want to test the type.

However, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof , the `typeof` operator doesn't do arrays. It treats them as objects. After some digging around, I found [How to check if an object is an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-array) , saying to use `Array.isArray` to test whether or not it is an array, but other than looping over everything, is there a way to test whether or not the given variable is an array of `foo`?

Or do I remember correctly that `new Foo()===new Foo()` is never true? If so, does this meant that it is impossible to test what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but other than looping over everything, is there a way to test whether or not the given variable is an array of foo?

No, but such looping is quite easy, just check if `every` item passes an `instanceof` check:

```js
function Foo() {}
function bar(arr) {
  if (!arr.every(item => item instanceof Foo)) {
    console.log('Bad arguments');
    return;
  }
  console.log('OK');
}

const f = new Foo();
bar([f]);
bar([1]);
```

Comment: Thanks! What does this setTimeout thing do? I'm not sure I understand the second half of your code.

Comment: It was a way of throwing an error in one part of the code while also allowing the other part to work normally. I'll change it to a `console.log`