# How to properly check if router.query.param is string or []string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using Next.js + typescript and doing the following:

```js
const MyPage = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState("")
    const router = useRouter()
    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.isReady) {
            if (router.query.status) {
               setStatus(router.query.status)
            }
        }

    }, [router])
    return <div>Status: {status} </div>
}
```

What is the best way to check if `router.query.status` is **string** or **[]string** ?

Should I do this?

```
if (Array.isArray(router.query.status)) {
    const y = router.query.status[0]
    setStatus(y)
}
```

I want to make sure that someone doesn't put extra parameters and break the code like this:

`example.com/?status=foo&status=bar`

which will result in **router.query.status** to be an array.

is there a better way to do that? or should I just keep using **isArray** method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4775722/2873538

Comment: Using `Array.isArray` is completely fine.