# Nest.js Multiple Query Parameters with Same Name

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Controller

```
@Get(')
test(
    @Param('accountId') accountId: string,
    @Query('propertyName') propertyNames: string[],
) {
    console.log(propertyNames);
}
```

Sample Request `localhost:8000?propertyName=test2&propertyName=test3`

Output:

> `[ 'test2', 'test3' ]`

This works fine when I have multiple values, but when only one parameter is sent, it creates a string instead of an Array

Request: `localhost:8000?propertyName=test3`
Generates the output: `test3` instead of `[test3]`

My current approach is to use (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775737/5236575)

`propertyName = [].concat(propertyName)`

to ensure the value is an array.

Is there a way to force Nest.js to parse the query parameters as a string array at all times as this is required in multiple places across controllers.

---

Note:
ValdiationPipe: `transform` is set to `true`

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you could use `@Transform` decorator from `class-transformer` to achieve that. You could move the logic of transforming a single string parameter to array with help of that decorator.

Comment: Will try it, but would it handle both an array as well as a string? since it is an array when multiple values come in.

Comment: The implementation is up to you:) The callback will just receive the value, then you can do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom pipe like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class ParseQueryValuePipe implements PipeTransform<string, string[]> {
  transform(value: string | string[]): string[] {
    if (value) {
      // You could even perform your validation here
      if (some_condition) {
        throw new BadRequestException('your_message');
      }


      return [value].flat();
    }
  }
}
```

and then you'd use it like this:

```
@Query('propertyName', new ParseQueryValuePipe()) propertyNames: string[],
```